# Display Basic Guidelines in New Question Window

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users

Recently, I have been looking through the top meta posts and have come across quite a few discussions regarding the poor quality of many questions. I am not too active on SO, but it seems that a common cause of the poor quality questions are new users that are unfamiliar with the SO guidelines or good practices. One feature that could help increase the quality of the questions could be a list of the basic guidelines for questions in the "new question window" ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)).

It wouldn't have to be extensive, but enough to give an idea at-a-glance about the general format of a good  question, detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (or anywhere else for that matter). 
The actual implementation could be an extension of the "How to ask" panel currently seen in the new question page. Having these suggestions directly on the ask page will let more users see them without having to click any links. This way the new users will have a sense for what goes into a new question.

Would something like this actually make an effect?

P.S. This is my first time posting on meta, so I'm probably proving my point.

Comment: New users are required to take the [tour] (and at least in theory do, although most clearly just click through and don't bother to actually do so). Why should everyone else be annoyed by the appearance of the extra screen clutter that those same users will also ignore?

Comment: When I was young, I didn't RTFM, nowadays I do. Things go smoother.

Comment: The problem with most suggestions is that we can't *force* new users to read something. While it may work in theory, in practice the users just click through and ignore everything. That said, I think that - for new users - a list of some relevant [meta-tag:question-quality] [meta-tag:faq] questions on the ask question page would be a reasonable improvement, as the users are not forced to read anything but those users who would read it have easier access to the information. I know that finding relevant information on meta can be... un-intuitive(?) for new users.

Comment: After 8 years of SO being the dominant programmer help site, the notion that the Universe still has new users is highly overrated.  You have to live under serious strata of rock to never have seen an SO Q+A before, existing Q+A ranks high in all the search engines.  SO users don't follow guidelines because they don't have to and nobody is forcing them to.  Asking a good question is hard work, forever at odds with the notion that SO is there to save programmers time.  Which works just fine when you google, but shouldn't when you don't.

Answer (score 3):

This is an idea we've been considering for a while here (allowing new users to use a question-ask form that's more akin to a wizard than a blank page, rather than providing a "wall of guidance" upfront).

It's hard to tell what effect this might have before experiment with it, but we think it's worth eventually trying it on the bigger sites of the network (to be effective, the form would need to be specific to the site you're using — e.g. on Stack Overflow, we'd ask for your code or for an exception, etc.).