# Let's improve Stack Overflow's "Ask a Question" page!

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users, question-quality

We've all heard and done our fair share of complaining about declining question quality. <sup>[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324083/is-stack-overflow-losing-its-shine?), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324072/how-to-lure-professionals-to-stack-overflow), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316112/can-we-care-a-little-more-about-quality-instead-of-quantity-please), [5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late), [6](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal), [7](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no)</sup> Various ideas have been floated, but haven't gotten significant traction for various reasons. Here's another attempt to roll up our sleeves and *do something constructive* about it.

In a recent somewhat-controversial post that considered solving this problem by [being more restrictive about new user registrations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324220/should-stack-overflow-be-more-restrictive-about-new-user-registrations), this random dude named [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) wandered by our humble site and [suggested that we improve the /ask page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325819/366904):

> **Why hasn't the /ask page meaningfully changed since 2010?**
>
> Here's a screenshot of the ask page circa 2009 from the wayback machine, next to what it looks like right now today in 2016.
>
> [image: SO ask page, 2009 vs 2016]
>
> I'd argue that the ask page is the one page on Stack Overflow that has changed the least in the last 5 years. Given the increasing volume of questions, and the [importance of question quality to the whole Q&A ecosystem](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) — that's … strange.
>
> If you want to reach new askers, you need a better /ask page. A whole lot better. How can this page interactively teach new users how to ask better, and raise the bar for the quality of the questions being asked?

**It's a good question.** Although there are undoubtedly other ways of addressing declining question quality, at least this is a constructive way to begin. And granted, it won't fix everything. [Everyone knows](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html) that [users don't read](http://uxmyths.com/post/647473628/myth-people-read-on-the-web), but even if we just reach a minute percentage of askers this way, [that can still make a big difference, given the site's scale](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324220/should-stack-overflow-be-more-restrictive-about-new-user-registrations#comment355288_325819).

**So let's do it!** In order to do it, we need to come up with concrete ideas on what needs to change and how to improve [the existing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). **Please take some time to ruminate over this, and then post your ideas as answers.**

<sub>(This question has a very similar title to "[Let's improve the How to Ask page(s)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258251/lets-improve-the-how-to-ask-pages)", and is quite similar in spirit. However, I'm focusing specifically on the [/questions/ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page, not the longer FAQ-style ["How to Ask" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to which it subtly links.)</sub>

Comment: Can't we get some attention from UX.se users. I assume they have the knowledge, we only know how to shift bits ...

Comment: Well, I'd say we need to at least come up with some ideas of our own, based on our personal knowledge of the community and what we ideally expect out of the page. Asking a UX expert is part of the refinement phase, once we have some concepts. You can't just show up there and post a "debug-my-UX" question. :-) @rene

Comment: I thought that Jeff's post was a bit of a cheap shot, too much like "you have to do what I didn't do".  Even back when he was still around I never understood why he didn't block questions with one or two sentences.  We generally expect users to show research, can't do that with this little text.  Simple to do.  But I must be overlooking something, the company has consistently refused to make asking a question a bit more work than using Google.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309235/3001761

Comment: what about interstitial page shown to new users? [/questions/ask/advice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?)

Comment: While I fully support this, I don't really know if question quality is *declining*. Maybe you just notice more errors and have less patience as you gain more experience?

Comment: We've been discussing this internally for the past few weeks, so we're on it.

Comment: Making a minimal, complete, verifiable example  (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I think is the most valuable, least heeded advice by new questioners.  Would be great to see that idea more prominently featured in first-timer support.  Producing the mcve often results in a would-be OP answering the question before asking it.

Comment: A year ago [Tim said](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295758/1529630) they would improve the ask page. But SO staff seem occupied with much more important things, like coding a [Jon Skeet game](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unikong) :(

Comment: I think SO is good as it is.. It's easy for people to ask, and it's easy to get the questions unanswered if the question itself isn't even trying. The point is, SO doesn't complicate users to ask question which is just enough for me.

Comment: @bluefeet In the past, suggestions of this sort were generally shot down with "people who post crap questions are not going to pay attention anyway". I'm not saying that was the *official* stance but it did stand out as a significant flaw in Meta discussions: why spend the effort adding all those bells and whistles if it is not going to make a noticeable difference? Is there evidence that you and your colleagues have that this may be *too* pessimistic a view, or that an experiment should be conducted to test whether this pessimistic view is justified?

Comment: @Louis I can only speak for myself, I personally feel that if we offered more guidance to users when they ask a question that _might_ help them formulate it. There will always be people who don't care and will post low quality questions, we can't do anything about those users. All we can do is try to provide better guidance/tools for users when asking, that's what I raised several weeks ago as something we need to look at.  We're in the process of looking at testing changes to the page, we're working thru what exactly we're going to test before making changes.

Comment: I don't know whether this is a good suggestion but many times i notice new users tagging  too many languages *(maybe hoping to get more attention just like you tag more people on social media)*, sometime it's absolutely appropriate but many times not.. Anyway they can edit their question but some tend to down-vote such posts which abuse tag usage..as the question topic is improving ask a question page... I think it'd be better if a notification something like "are you sure? You tagged more than 1 language" pops up when a new user tags more than 1 language.

Comment: The only thing that's declined is long-time users' _perception_ of question quality. SO looks beautiful via Google, very handy after asking even a barely-passable question, reasonable after a quick browse of the site, and horrendous after seeing the junk that gets constantly posted. As long as good questions still get good answers (which I've admittedly had trouble with lately), the site is still as useful as it's ever been.

Comment: tl;dr: Sorry if this is a repeat; it is not in the [Related] section to the right. [Should the MCVE page advise against pictures of text?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327051).

Comment: Yes, it should be easier for the new comers to find the relevant questions, and save their time(and effort) and question before getting marked as 'duplicate'.

Comment: Too many posts in triage/first post are responded to with a link to MCVE. That should be in the how to ask page

Comment: Why is this not on [meta.SE]? It concerns everybody, and other sites may have different requirements you may want to keep in mind *now*.

Comment: @Raphael This discussion does *not* concern everybody. It is limited specifically to Stack Overflow, hence why it was posted on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray Yea, as if potential changes would not be pushed to the whole network eventually. Anyway, if it is not *intended* to apply to the whole network, I move it should be; [SO] is  not the only site with question quality issues.

Comment: @Raphael The intention here is to improve the Ask page *specifically for Stack Overflow*. The site is the oldest and largest in the network, and has quality problems above and beyond what any other site can possibly imagine. Most of our users are willing to resort to extreme options to try to improve the quality of questions. Creating a New User Question Wizard is a compelling option on Stack Overflow, but makes little sense on other sites. Nor is it likely to be supported by those sites' communities. Stack Overflow does a *lot* of things differently that aren't pushed to other sites.

Comment: Analysis: New questions get capricious receptions (initial votes, harsh or nice comments), probably answered (maybe a *great answer*, but probably not), and then further contextually voted on (questions that get good answers tend to get upvoted themselves). If Stack Overflow offers guidance to new askers, we'd get better questions, but when the better questions are met with a poor reception, Stack Overflow would appear more responsible - harder to blame the users. Who wants to be responsible for making the site look bad? Safest bet is not to change. Only a true leader would suggest otherwise.

Comment: Some of my previous suggestions for what they're worth: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly

Comment: *We've been discussing this internally for the past few weeks, so we're on it. – bluefeet♦ Jun 26 '16 at 13:34*

Comment: Were some of the suggestions here implemented? Weren't there some changes to the wizard in the past 3-4 years?

Comment: @Peter Yes, there's a whole new ask question page now.

Answer (score 211):

*Make sure to read [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327028) from Rachel as well which solves the clumsiness of this wizard*

I understand that Stack Overflow wants to keep the bar low to post a question because that is the whole reason the site exist. However the fierce moderation scare users away after their first post and the ones that give it a second shot run the risk of hitting an almost irreversible question ban.

If we are going to change the Ask Question page, its design goal should be:

- prevent posting of a question by users that really don't care
- being helpful for users that do care
- not being a big hurdle

The new page should be tailored to your *ask question level*: beginner, competent and expert.<sup>[1](http://www.rebeccawestburns.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=57:five-stages-of-acquiring-expertise-novice-to-expert&Itemid=187)</sup>
I'm a fan of [the question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), so my proposal is an attempt to create room for those checks.

For the beginner, the Ask Question page should really be a Wizard, with 5 pages:

- page 1: **Intro**. At the top the required action, in the content it should explain the process of asking a question, at the right links, at the bottom the `I'm ready to proceed` call to action.
- page 2: **Body**. At the top 3 or 4 hints how to write a good question, in the content the question body and preview , at the right links to formatting, at the bottom the `My question is clear and properly formatted` call to action. If possible, you could run a server side syntax check, quality score and show its outcome.
- Page 3: **Title**. At the top the hints about good and bad title. In the content the title input box with the duplicate title search. If hits are returned, you can point out that asking a duplicate is not wise. At the bottom the call to action `My title accurately summarizes my question`.
- Page 4: **Tags**. At the top show tags, excerpts, and wikis. In the content 5 vertical placeholders for tags. When a tag is chosen, show the excerpt and the first 100 characters of the tag wiki. At the bottom call to action `These tags are relevant for my question`.
- Page 5: **Post Question**. At the top show hints what down-votes mean, what comments are for, and how to edit. In the content show a preview of the question. At the bottom call to action `My question is complete and ready to post`.

The whole idea is to be able to provide the user with information and guidance that fits their goal. Writing a title is a different task than writing and formatting text, while correctly categorizing your question is another separate task. Those three need their own guidance and active feedback, and in the end all those tasks should fit together perfectly to have the best result.

For the competent (anyone with 1 question asked), the wizard is down to two pages, with the first page showing the score of their previous questions. When that score is less than zero, they received down-votes, or had their question closed, it should explain ways that they can improve their questions. Page 2 can be the title, body and tags, as it is now. It can show links to the guidance that was in the novice wizard. The call to action when the previous score was bad should be `This question has fixed the problems that my previous one had`. If the score was OK, a neutral call to action can be used.

For the expert (exact criteria are open for discussion but let's say for now: above 3 questions, without down- or close-votes, or 5 questions, no matter what) the Ask Question page is the same one we use now. Just one page, no wizard.

In no way I'm a UX type of person but with my limited skills this is a mock-up of the title page of my proposal:

[image: mockup of one wizard page]

Comment: Thanks! This is brilliant stuff and almost exactly what I was hoping to see someone come up with when I asked the question. I'm warming up more and more to the "wizard"-based approach, especially for beginners and those whose questions have not been well-received thus far.

Comment: @CodyGray oh boy. let me add a disclaimer: IANAUE  and most of the UX peeps I talk to hate wizards so don't have high hopes this will be implemented .....

Comment: Well, I'm not really worried about improving the UX of posting a question; we'll still have plenty! The problem with wizards, as I understand it, is the average user is not a linear thinker and doesn't like being boxed in with a wizard's restrictive workflow. But wizards were invented by programmers because they match the way we think and solve problems. So I think this makes a lot of sense for SO. Obviously it wouldn't be rolled out to other SE sites, but they don't have the same quality problem (and certainly not on the same scale) that we do, so they can keep their zero-friction approach.

Comment: I think this is a great idea. Given that we want to teach new users how to properly use the site and such "wizard functionality" is restricted only to those users and provides a little bit of training seems the perfect solution.

Comment: That's really brilliant. It might be even more helpful if some pages include examples (templates or placeholders - like my answer suggests).

Comment: That's a great idea! Wizards really help when one doesn't really know how to do this or that or when they're not sure what to do to make something _better_.

Comment: I fell victim to the question ban before an account merger of a sock puppet account and then it was magically lifted.

Comment: I had exactly the same idea. Having a wizard allows the information to be displayed more clearly as well, compared to what we have now.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. But wouldn't it make more sense to ask them to formulate a clear title before the rest of the post?

Comment: Looks really nice. Generally tags should not be included in titles. For the **Title** and **Tags** pages might the tags be partially filled from the title and an updated title suggested, but that would easily create very poor titles. Might the two pages be combined and the page has a message saying that their title contains xxx which would be better as a tag and that they should check that tag and the updated title are correct.

Comment: Good Idea. How about creating the body of the question in multiple steps with help of a wizard? For example "Introduction" - "Problem Statement" - "MCWE / Code" (maybe with a "Language" dropdown) - "How to reproduce" or something similar? Of course with relevant example text or helpful links for each section. Finally, you should see the entire question with markdown + preview to review it.

Comment: Very good proposal. I think the beginner wizard should probably stay for a bit longer than just for the first question. It could go away after the following conditions are met: 1) user has posted at least 3 questions; *and* 2) all questions have a non-negative score. This means that if the user insists on asking poor/down-voted questions, then the wizard should remain in place even if the user is about to ask question 10, as he has clearly not gotten the message yet. The length of the wizard might be enough of a hurdle to discourage question-whoring from them. Wizard goes away for better users

Comment: Would it be possible to run a duplicate check based on the question body, instead of its title? If that's not doable, I think the title should be presented before or in the same page as the question body. I'm worried that if users are only shown potential duplicates _after_ they have done all the work of writing the question, they'll be reluctant to give it all up.

Comment: @JacobFord search is expensive and I don't want to introduce anything that will have impact on performance. Title search already exists now. The reason the title is last because that is suggested in the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): *If you're having trouble summarizing the problem, write the title last*.

Comment: Interestingly, [I suggested a wizard](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324223/215552) on [Brad's question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324220/215552) a while back and got shot down. Of course, this is a much, much better answer to a question more focused on question asking rather than user registration. Got my vote :)

Comment: I think the hand-holding can be helpful, but the wizard-as-a-sequence-of-page-navigations is terrible.  People need to be able to do non-linear editing.  What if while typing the question you realize there's a better title?  If these steps are all presented on the same page, possibly using reveals to prevent skipping one, fine.  But out-of-order improvements need to be well supported.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree, that is why I proposed to ONLY do this on the first question asked and fallback to a two-page format after that and then to the current format. I do allow for navigation back and forth but the first time asker has to endure this *hand-holding*

Comment: I am a huge fan of the wizard concept; I think I even suggested in on some other thread at some other time (or maybe it was in a comment?). Clearly, great minds think alike :-) However, I would add more sections. Force the user to add some code (at least for stackoverflow proper), and make sure they've used the four-spaces-for-indent markup.  Maybe force them to list one or two web searches they did to solve the problem. Make sure that at least one sentence somewhere ends with a question mark.

Comment: I want to like the wizard idea, since I would like to see such a simple solution -- but I just don't see it helping. The process would become too abstract, and breaking process apart isn't really required on the web anymore. Ajax loading provides for many of these suggestions to simply be done in-line.

Comment: @BryanOakley - Not all questions require code though.

Comment: @TravisJ: agreed, though I bet the percentage goes way up when talking about newbie questions specifically on SO, which is what this wizard mostly addresses. Perhaps they can check a checkbox that says "I have no code", and that goes into a special review queue. I think the goal of the wizard is to teach people who don't know how to ask questions (which seems like 95% of SO users...) that a good question has a title, it has a description, it has code, it has a description of research that was done. I'm sure there could be an effective way to handle exceptions.

Comment: Another thought might be to add a disclaimer at the top of the wizard: "**Attn advanced programmers:..**". The disclaimer would be something like "bear with us, we are trying to weed out low quality questions. This isn't targeted to you; we know it's tedious for your first question, but we feel it's necessary". Experienced users will be accepting (I think),and newbies won't read it :-).

Comment: @CodyGray I found the large image better, especially when this answer is the most voted (and probably most interesting one).

Comment: Also that would mean that wiki some tags will have to be edited to ensure that the first 100 character are really relevant and not just an intro to something longer ?

Comment: @Walfrat sure, they can can be clickable. At least this gives the users the hint that tags have info. And it might also encourage more of us to provide good wiki content. It could be a win-win situation

Comment: This is very similar to something I was thinking about but instead of multiple pages, it would be broken into multiple boxes on the same page. But we'd have helpful tips, etc before each box, etc.

Comment: @bluefeet I have thought about that as well. I'm afraid that for the users that are challenged in asking a good question, to much info at once is daunting and likely to be ignored, assuming they are used to a forum, google or facebook. Giving them a simple, clear and well defined goal for each step I think it is much more likely that they: consume the guidance given, get an end result that we are happy with and hopefully is remembered on the next question. So maybe a bit of A/B testing for both scenario's with a closed test group can reveal what is really needed

Comment: I'm a UI developer, and am very anti-wizard. From my experience, users just try to solve whatever lets them hit "Next", without trying to take in the info given. Like @bluefeet, I would much rather see expandable areas, tooltips, or on-demand information being used. This way, the user *asks* for the info, and is much more likely to retain it. I am thinking more along the lines of reddit's Submit Post page which says *"Wait! Before posting, know we have rules. Read this **short** list before posting, and if you do want more guidance to improve your chances of getting good answers, go here"*

Comment: @Rachel thanks for acknowledging that UX people have moved beyond wizards. I think expandable areas would achieve the same effect as a wizard, as long as each area has a single goal and the guidance matches the context. So your idea would be an up to date/modern of my initial suggestion.

Comment: @rene I don't have time to post an answer now, but my end goal would be to keep the page simple and short, with the user able to easily and quickly access any additional information they want without leaving the page. If you give them a wall of text, they won't read it. Give them multiple sections they have to go through, they'll just try to do the minimum that allows them to hit "Next". But keep it short and to the point, with ability to get more info on demand fast (ie. "Ok site has rules, what are those rules?", "Wtf is a Tag?", "What makes a good question?" etc), and they'll actually learn

Comment: @MarounMaroun I love the template idea. How about "My program does not work" wizard?

Comment: @bluefeet, rene, I posted [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327028/302677) to try to explain my thought process. Forcing a bunch of information, no matter how good, on the user is not nearly as efficient as giving them the shortest possible amount of information they need to know, and having them query the additional information on their own. Our goal should be to make sure the information is arranged in a way that is easy and quick for the user to retrieve exactly what they want when they want it.

Comment: Not a single freehand circle. I am disappoint

Comment: This is excellent - I think there should also be a check for a line break. I don't think there'd be an ontopic question that can be asked in one paragraph - but instead of asking for a line break - it comes up with an error of some other sort. e.g. if text.length>n *format the question* if text.length<n *ensure there is enough detail*

Answer (score 95):

I really like the solutions many of you have been proposing, so I would like to give it a shot with another approach

Some questions can fit some broad categories easily, and I would say many have some common points in them. So I propose showing a menu with possible question categories for the user to pick from, like this (sorry for the lack of better artistic skills, design software, and typography taste):

[image: Ask Question Menu]

**First Category:**

- **Similar Questions:** Why doesn't this work? = I have an error = Code is wrong

  - User explains what is he doing.
  - User may specify what error he has.
  - User may show his code.
  - User may write an example of what the correct result should be.

[image: I have error Section]

**Second Category:**

- **Similar Questions:** How to do this? = How do I do such and such? = How can I do that?

  - User asks how to do something.
  - User may explaining the steps he took.
  - User may show his code.
  - User may explain why it didn't work.

[image: How To Section]

And so on... you get the idea. (I couldn't come up with a third category, hence the magical option #3)

This questions/points are just meant to divide the body of the question into more precise points. Things like the title and tags would remain as they are (or could be improved by what [@rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326873/1305745) and [@Rachel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327028/1305745) propose).

At first I though it would be a good idea that only when all the text fields are filled, the submit button may be enabled... but as you may have thought by now, some of the category's questions/points could be entirely optional. So to address that problem, I would suggest putting icons next to each field. Once the user is done typing in one of the field (and it meets some basic validations), a friendly green check would show up next to the field to indicate it was filled correctly. Once enough fields are filled, the submit button would be enabled.

Once the question is submitted, the fields would just get stitched together (maybe with titles separating each field) to create the question body we now know and love. The benefits of this would be questions that have the necessary information that follow a logical sequence. They would save SO users the trouble of asking in the comments things like "what have you tried?" and "what is your error?", and it would try to protect new users from the negative effects of being nagged for their own naivety. I know this wouldn't be perfect, as a user can just misinterpret the question and/or type whatever he pleases, but it could be just enough improve the quality of the overall new users questions.

Of course this is just a naive generalization of questions. The option #1 and #2 look similar the way I've structured them. I bet some more experienced users may be able to identify and categorize the questions better, and define what questions/points are the most relevant that need to be present when asking such types of questions.

I don't mean to replace the current format. Some questions may never fall under a specific category, and I know the more experienced users won't need their hands held through the process of asking a question. That's why I left option #4 there, people may just continue to the current "Ask a question format" without any hassle.

The point of all this is categorization, is making some click and fill forms for novice users that aren't very familiar with asking for help in a clear manner. I believe that using this, these inexperienced users can learn what type of information they must provide if they want their question answered.

Comment: Something somewhat similar has been proposed for AskUbuntu ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/czpN9.png)), see [Alpha-testing a wizard](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7198) and [Shouldn't Stack Exchange build a Question Wizard? (for beginning users)](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13498)

Comment: I kind of like this idea, but it is a dramatic shift away from our current Ask Question page and would only apply to SO. I'm not sure if it could be easily written to be generic and apply to all Q&A sites in the SE network

Comment: @Rachel Making it generic would miss the point. We should focus on specific problem areas for each site. It's a lot like finding the right "writing prompt." We should also have categories for off-topic or bad questions, like "What is the best tool to do X?" which explains why it's off topic, what we're trying to achieve by calling it off-topic, and gives the user some tips on how to make their question more on-topic.

Comment: Definitely a good idea. This wouldn't solve all the problems, but **it would certainly work for anyone who would have been receptive to comments asking the same things**. Why wait until *after* the question has been posted to ask "What have you tried?" "Did you see an error message? What did it say?", when we can ask that *while* the question is being posted. As an advantage, it helps people along the way of writing a question, which many people say is an extremely daunting experience. Good stuff here; thanks for sharing your ideas! (PS: I don't think other SO sites need this like we do...)

Comment: @Rachel: I agree with **jpaugh** and **CodyGray**. The question categories shouldn't be generic to all SO sites as they vary very much in content. It maybe even not be for all SO sites, but for example, in the Android SO site I've noticed people come with questions that fall under some categories like *"How do I root"*, *"Why isn't this working"*, etc., and we always have to ask the user's *phone model*, *OS version*, *the error that poped-up* and *what steps did they try*, as they don't realize that including that info in their question would be very helpful.

Comment: @JonasCz yes, what I propose is very similar to the [Alpha-testing a wizard](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7198), but the difference is that this would be a *1-screen-wizzard*. Once a category is selected you go straight to writing information about your question, instead of going through many steps that require users to think/choose more.

Comment: I really like this and I'm probably going to take the idea and run with it, building off this, Alpha-testing a wizard, and some understanding of the concerns in Rachel's post below.

Comment: This is the best idea I've seen here so far - it forces the user to post the relevant bits and let's face it - at some point - if they cannot follow this - how on earth can they understand how to program?

Comment: I think this is pretty good idea. The artwork could be cleaned up in an edit. I think a small suggestion might be: if the novice user is ready to click the submit, it might be wise to have an option to "share draft with SO expert" feature, to share with a seasoned SO expert before it gets shared with the world. The SO expert could provide coaching to that user if the user is straying too far from the guidelines (and is running the risk of getting heavily downvoted and discouraged in the future, and perhaps humiliated on a global forum).

Answer (score 91):

Show, don't tell!

I [still think](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296353/show-examples-of-good-and-bad-questions) the team should consider **showing examples of good and bad questions**, linked to from the "ask question" page  - possibly selected dynamically based on the tags the user enters*.

An example would show a typical Stack Overflow question with problems. Problematic areas could be highlighted. When you click on the highlights, you get a popup with an explanation what is wrong (e.g. "The question title should summarize the problem, not only contain the name of the product you are using."  or "Remember to capitalize i's." etc. etc.)

At any time, you could switch to a view of the question where the problems are fixed.

Arriving at a set of meaningful examples would not be an easy task.

- There mustn't be too many examples, or people won't read them.
- Still, they have to cover all the most common problems that exist.
- The examples need to demonstrate how to "fix" a question - yet they musn't be so specific that everyone starts following, cargo cult-like, *exactly* the pattens shown in the fixes.

Etc. etc.

It could be worth the investment in time and effort, though, if the result were a more accessible way to teach people.

<sub>* = That might necessitate putting the "tags" field before anything else, which is a different discussion.</sub>

Comment: Plus-one for the note about remembering to capitalize "i".

Comment: I would advise against picking questions dynamically from the site. This works very poorly in the low quality review audits that try to find low and high quality questions. I think some hand-picked "canonical" questions would be better, even if they don't contain the topic that the poster is interested in.

Comment: @Lundin oh, absolutely. The only way this could work is by hand-picking questions. Explaining the problems, how to fix them, etc. would totally be manual work (and a lot of it)

Comment: I like the idea of including more signal for the user with regards to what not to do. In my opinion, one angle which could be addressed that has a very high amount of unused signal is *the roomba*. The roomba will remove questions which were closed after 30 days if it did not have any answers and was <0 score. These questions could be included in an additional related set (or used as statistical indication of post quality) as an indication of how strongly the current question is matching up to poorly received questions.

Comment: I think this would be a great idea, however I don't think it belongs directly on the Ask Question page. It should be part of the "how to ask a good question" guide for those users that are seeking that knowledge instead.

Comment: As an alternative to 'showing' them good/bad questions you could 'quiz' the user as to which is which and not allow them to post until they have gotten X of these right. It should be obvious but requires the user to at least READ what is posted.

Comment: You should follow "remember to capitalize i's" with "because more people will respond"

Comment: This sounds similar to an old request I made a while back: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly

Comment: This is a good idea (modulo correct implementation) in the same way that the examples given for good question titles are a very useful linkable resource

Comment: Totally agree - so many people are struggling to understand some comments under their questions, let alone the help centre - diagrams are helpful

Answer (score 60):

TL;DR version: New questions start out in deleted-by-author state, then a self-review page takes them through possible duplicates (and possibly other self-improvement steps) culminating in an undelete-by-author action.

---

I've [posted suggestions before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253339/help-askers-find-duplicates-before-the-question-becomes-public) but I still think the biggest problem is the workflow associated with duplicates.  I hope I can explain more concisely than I did the last time around.

Right now the workflow is:

1. Enter a title
2. Site shows a list of questions which are usually completely unrelated, because a title is not much to go on for natural text matching algorithms.  In particular because no tags are entered yet and we discourage putting tags in the title, most of the suggestions will be for completely different languages / frameworks
3. Visiting any of the suggested questions navigates away from the Ask a Question page
4. At some point after the question is mostly typed in (in the early stages, "What to ask about" and "Markdown syntax" blurbs are shown instead) a related list that generally DOES have an existing answer appears.  It's off to the side which suggests that it doesn't need to be dealt with, and because the color scheme matches the Markdown instructions already shown, askers may not even notice that the sidebar changed.
5. If the user does see something in the sidebar and clicks on it, it causes navigation away from the ask-a-question, the site saves a draft but users aren't told this.  Instead, their browser probably pops up a warning that the form contents may be lost, which is **REALLY FREAKING SCARY** to the user because they now have a lot of effort invested in typing up their question.
6. Adding tags makes the related question list even better, but the change is still undiscoverable, and the navigation problem still exists.

A better workflow:

1. Enter title, without being harassed with questions related to other frameworks taking up half the page (I'm not against swapping this with tags, as others suggest, but that's not the key point of this answer)
2. Type question, without having the Markdown help disappear halfway through.
3. Choose tags
4. Click the completion button, which is now renamed from "Post Question" to "Save and Review"
5. The next screen has related questions, identified using all available information (title+content+tags) front-and-center, followed by a repeat of the preview shown while editing, and a link to make further edits.
6. On the related questions, a banner appears at the top with buttons for "I found my answer." and "Back to my question".  We can include something about "If this does not answer your question, please make sure you have explained why your situation is different, otherwise our experts may suggest approaches you've already seen."
7. Below the list of related questions is the real "Post Question" button.

Checking out related questions doesn't involve navigating away from a form, so the user isn't scared of losing their work.
This does require some additional backend support, although existing support for question deleted by the author comes very close.

The question is now saved server-side, not just using cookies.  The user can have more than one question in this phase at once, unlike the draft.  It follows them between computers, unlike the draft.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that having a "Save and Review" button, leading to a preview page would be a good step on its own, entirely apart from the other good thoughts here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Sure, that is a good place to do all sorts of things, such as checklists and so on.  The important thing is that we're providing a way to give extra help to the asker in a way that doesn't interrupt writing, which is a rather fragile process (at least, the process of writing a PhD dissertation was for me) and doesn't require them to notice when a sidebar changes.  I feel that allowing saving of the question server-side is a very important change... and if it leads to saving several times during writing the question, who's to say that's a bad thing.  "Save then Edit More" button?

Comment: I like this. It is thinking a bit outside the box, but you certainly do point out some very real usability problems with the current "Ask Question" page. I honestly don't ask enough questions to have ever noticed many of these. Disappearing UI is never really a good idea, and hiding this important help like it's an ad in the sidebar does seem stupid. All users are ad-blind now. That said, I and others have actually found the suggested "related questions" to be better than what I normally get doing a site search (not better than Google though).

Comment: I'm worried about users only seeing potential duplicates after they have put in the effort of writing out the entire question. I know I get more reluctant to give something up the longer I spend on it. But I do think the positive language of "I found my answer" would be much more successful than the negative shame of marking your labor as a duplicate.

Comment: @JacobFord: I'm not suggesting removing search.  Ideally people find their answers without ever using the "Ask Question" page.  (There are probably improvements that can be made to search).  But some duplicates are found by comparison of the full-text of both questions, you can't get there without the effort of typing the question.  And exactly because that is a high effort, the site needs to provide as much support for making it as painless as possible -- by not interrupting the writing process with page navigation, and by saving the user's work early and often, not just in unreliable cookies

Comment: I like the idea of making “Draft questions” first-class things for my own sake, not just new users! It would be nice for that "Okay, I wrote my question and now I realize I need to do more research" stage, or "I'm working on a really polished self-answer." Of course, the existing draft system can help with those, but it doesn't **feel saved**.

Answer (score 51):

I'm a little late to this question, but I've been working in UI development for years now, with a specific focus on user experience, so thought I'd add my opinion.

The [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) page should be as short and simple as possible, while containing many areas to allow users to easily and quickly access additional information on demand without leaving the page.

The goal is to have the user only aware of the minimal they need to know.

1. **We have rules.** Click here to view a short simplified list of them. If you still want help understanding a rule, click it to view advanced detailed version.
2. **Not all questions are successful.** Click here to see checklist of what you can do to improve your chances at posting a successful question, or for seeing if your question meets the recommended criteria.
3. **We allow both wiki-style formatting and code formatting.** Click here for help with syntax or to see examples.

I did a rough sketch in Balsamiq to try and get my idea across, although its nothing refined :

[image]

**Things to Note**

- Single Page. No wizard, no navigating away, very basic with only things you "need the user to know right now" there.
- Get rid of the "Questions that may have your answer" box. It's almost never accurate, takes up valuable space, and adds to the clutter. If you want, add the Search option somewhere else behind something, such as the link to "did you do your research".
- Rapid On-Demand information in the form of tooltips and expanders wherever we can. If a user is presented with information up front, there is a much higher chance they will ignore it (and other relevant information) because there's too much. If they instead request the information somehow, there is a much higher chance they will retain knowledge.

  It's like the difference between saying *"Use a foo, which is a device used for a, b, and c provided by d, to do X"*, versus just saying *"Use a foo to do X"*, where if users know they can hover over the word "foo" to get more details/context if needed.
- Rearrange so that question details is the focal point, and title is at the bottom. The title it's just a summarized version of your question, so typically you want the question first.
- Do something to make it clear the purpose of tags is to categorize content, like if you were in a library. I had no idea what tags were when I first started, and there are plenty of people who don't understand them either. I'd also make an overt recommendation to tag your question with your language/technology as well, perhaps as the example. And don't need to tell them "max 5 or min 1" unless they try to submit with an invalid # of tags, that text is just clutter.
- "Rules" and "Checklist" links should be expanders to show a short, simplified version of the rules/checklist, without taking the user away from the page or changing their current train of thought. The expanders should contain plenty of links to more detailed versions of each of the bullet points.
- Should probably include a show/hide preview" toggle link somewhere... I realized I forgot it in mockup. Personally I find the preview directly below my text box the most useful so I can see changes as I type or format text, so that would probably be what I'd recommend.

**Things to Avoid**

- Walls of text. Many users will just skim through
- Wizards of any kind. Many users jump to the automatic thought process of *"what do I have to do to hit Next"*, and that becomes their focus rather than learning anything. Plus, they're a pain to build properly in browsers.
- Any kind of navigation away from the current page. If you give them links to elsewhere to follow, do it in a new tab.
- Popup windows. They cover whatever the user was doing, and are commonly associated with being a nuisance.
- Don't treat the user like an idiot at first. If the first sentence I read is written for a 5 yr old, I'm going to skip or skim past all the other text too. Of course, it's always nice to have an idiot-proof version of whatever help text you have that you can link to in case the user requests more information.
- Don't use the sidebar for important information. This space is relegated to "not part of content" or "advertising space" in our mind while browsing because that is usually what it is, so it is often overlooked.

I'm sure the idea can be refined further, but hopefully this should give you a general idea of what a good "Ask Question" page should look like for general public use by a large uneducated user base.

Keep it simple with just the things they *need* to know on the page, allow access to concise on-demand information that doesn't take them away from their current train of thought, and hide all the idiot-proof documentation behind easy-to-find links where people actually say *"Wait I'm an idiot and still don't understand, I need more help!"*.

Comment: Ok, I see how this would work. What I find difficult to judge is if *beginner* users will understand that they need to follow the links and hover on the tooltips. In my wizard design you would at least have made sure that without any effort they got the most relevant guidance. But I think this can only be settled when field tested. What I absolutely don't like (sorry)   is your dismissal of the duplicate search. Maybe my hopes are to high on that but I would expect that at least some question don't get asked because a dupe is found before posting. I'm mentally not ready to give that up.

Comment: @rene There's a difference in writting a beginner page for someone new to the site vs writing a beginner page for someone new to using a computer or the internet. For example, wizards would be great for my grandma, but for today's internet crowd they are not needed and typically ignored. People want something fast, that they don't have to wade through a ton of text to find out. I think it's important when designing for the internet crowd today that things are short, concise, and provide standard indicators for where to go for more details if needed (ie. hyperlink, ? icon, etc).

Comment: @rene About the duplicate search, I think it would be fine somewhere else, or hidden unless the user chooses to expand it, but I think it is inaccurate and confusing enough that it should not be one of the first things presented to the user on the Ask page. It just adds clutter, and detracts of the message of *"these are the key things you **need** to know to perform this action, so take 2 seconds of your time to make sure you know them"*.

Comment: I'm happy to trust your experience. You have my vote and support for your proposal.

Comment: @rene I just noticed you linked to my answer at the top of yours, thanks! I figured my answer would get buried here since it's a late answer, but I had hopes that someone in charge of making decisions would read it and take it into consideration. Now it actually has a chance of getting seen and evaluated by more people too :D I think your answer is good as well and has some great points, although I really am against wizards, especially browser ones for the modern internet crowd :)

Comment: I appreciate this from an ease-of-use standpoint, and I think the use of the sidebar to convey important information is the biggest flaw in the current design. However, I'm not sure I see this significantly impacting the rate at which "bad" questions are asked, since (almost by definition) bad questions are typically asked by uses who don't read the rules, the guidelines, or even the tooltips.

Comment: @KyleStrand If you present users with a lot of information, they are unlikely to commit time to digest it before posting because it's a big time investment on their part with no known payoff. But if you keep things short, simple, and only tell them things they *need* to know, then they are far more likely to take in that information, and seek out more if they have questions and it's easy to find/read.

Comment: @KyleStrand For example, rather than dump all our rules on them at once, we just say "We have rules, know them before posting". If they want to know more (they will), they can expand to a *short* bullet pointed list that isn't too much for them to skim through. If they want more detail on individual bullets, they can click on a bullet to see the full details and examples. By that point, they're invested already, and they are actively seeking the content rather than us pushing it on them, and they are much more likely to read and retain the knowledge.

Comment: It's the "they will" part that I'm not sure about. All forums have rules; I am generally fairly scrupulous about attempting to follow the rules of online communities; and yet I still tend to assume that the rules for most online communities are probably more or less equivalent. This is *usually true* for forums, and SO gives the impression of being a forum. So, of course, one of the most common pieces of negative feedback for new users is "this is not a forum," which really means *our rules are different*--which users will **not** naturally expect.

Comment: @KyleStrand So maybe "We're not a forum. Our rules are different. Read them before posting." as the text?

Comment: I think this design fails a bit because it is trying to be all things to all user skill levels. I think you do, in fact, want a multi-page wizard layout for new users that just presents the minimum amount of information necessary and a single field to fill out. This would be a good design for intermediate and advanced users, though.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Oh I thought this was the minimum amount of information needed by and from new users XD Also, I'm basing this off my experience posting on reddit... as someone used to the internet but not to reddit, I thought they had a good Submit/Ask page. Most new users want to get things right, it's just they don't know what "right" is for the site, and don't want a huge time investment in figuring out if what they assume of a site is actually correct.

Comment: as I said in another reply, the minute "Reddit" is invoked, we have all failed miserably.

Comment: @JeffAtwood That's why I avoided use of "reddit" in my answer. But it doesn't change the fact that as a user, I found Reddit's Submit/Ask page to be much more user-friendly than StackOverflows. It only told me things I *needed* to know which kept it very short, and made it easy for me to read additional information

Comment: Don't discount wizards just because it takes a bit of effort to get through it.  If anything, it could act like a filter for those who will likely not spend enough time formulating a good question in the first place. If they can't wrap their head around learning how to "click Next", then they probably haven't even researched their question sufficiently before posting. Being confronted with the onslaught of sharp, sometimes rude comments and less-than-helpful advise to newbies is far worse than requiring someone to spend an extra few seconds and "effort" in a step-by-step approach.

Comment: Put a different way, a beginner "Ask a Question" wizard would be like a type of initiation--it might be "painful" to the impatient user, but inspire better participation. Perhaps offering bonus reputation or accelerated privileges would encourage new posters to actually choose an optional wizard. The impetus behind improvements is that new users **need to understand more details and accept more responsibility** before posting. Being compelled or enticed with privilege may be more effective than simply improving page design and using "standard indicators".

Answer (score 39):

Sometimes I find myself (even today, as an experienced user) looking at other users posts before I post my own. It helps me come up with better wording, grammar, style and formation.

The [Tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) shows an example of a well asked question along with its answers, and it highlights what should be asked (and what shouldn't):

[image: What should be asked]

Unfortunately, many users (most?) don't go through this page, and usually skip it or just scroll down to get a badge.

Since we see many low quality questions that are badly formatted, we can tell that many users don't really care about the "How to Ask" and "How to Format" side bars.

I'm thinking that instead of having wall of text of "How to Ask", we can provide a template<sup>*</sup> of a good question that has a two paragraphs of a description (including code formation for code-text) with a code snippet that users can take and change for their purposes.

I know that there are many different templates, and many different ways of asking a good question; some might have code, other might only have a description with possible image, it's not easy to have a *generic* template for a good question - But I'm just dropping the general idea of what I think might help a bit.

Example (of course it should be changed to something more general and make sure everyone understand that it's only a template for demonstration purposes):

[image]

This might help newcomers understand basic formation, while it also shows how a good question is asked.

<sup>* That template can actually be a placeholder that appears for users with < x reputation points</sup>

Comment: I wonder if we could identify a few different broad types or "classes" of questions, have the user select theirs from a list, and show a template that made sense with that type of question. For example, we could have one type of question that is about specific code (the "debug-my-code" question done correctly), another that is about a specific algorithm, another that is more like your example here, etc. It would make the posting experience more interactive and help to tailor the templates. The problem, of course, is it makes the questions pretty cookie-cutter, which I instinctively dislike...

Comment: @CodyGray I agree. Was about to suggest something very similar to rene's answer.

Comment: [Pre-fill question box with text for new users; A/B study proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278444)

Comment: I have always struggled with this particular question as a valid model for SO questions.

Comment: I wouldn’t encourage anyone to use backticks for technology names like “iOS”.

Comment: The example in this answer is arguably not the greatest, but a **massive** +1 for placeholder text showing an example of a 'good' question.

Comment: I agree on both the question's quality and formatting, will replace the image soon.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I did not mean to question your use of that particular Q/A rather that that question is one new users often see when they click on one of the help links (I am not sure which one).  I have always thought it was a bad example for a new user so I am not complaining that you used it rather I think it should not be exposed as a model of how to ask a question

Comment: I even think the new question is a problem, as a novice reading that I think it gives me license to ask something like Can I run Python code I wrote on my Windows machine on a Linux server?  I understand that you would see the difference between the two - but I am a novice and you are trying to improve my behavior.  I think something even more fundamental like the following I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080347/how-to-add-column-name-to-the-query-result-spring-jpa

Answer (score 35):

The easiest thing to do would be to *apply the tag to the search section*. How can users be expected to not post duplicates when the system itself cannot even locate them?

Here is a real world example: a user is unsure how to sort an array in JavaScript.

[image]

<sub>*yes, that is a hand drawn red circle angry face (re: swift, codeigniter, localization, Ruby, NSDate)*</sub>

Swift is Objective-C for those not familiar, which is to say it is most certainly not related to JavaScript whatsoever. In fact, **none of those results are relevant**.

The odd thing is that the search feature at Stack Overflow already provides for using tags as criteria. I would argue that the lack of tag searching in the ask question page is probably a large source of ending up with tag names in titles at this point.

Were the feature to automatically include the tag in the search, you would have gotten these results (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+sort+an+array+%5Bjavascript%5D) as number 1 and number 2

+148 [How to sort an array of objects with jquery or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript)

and

+219 [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

**This change is so easy**. It makes too much sense not to do, and it is also doing a disservice to question askers to not allow the system to locate duplicate content even when given the correct criteria.

tl;dr; **Include the chosen tags in the search criteria for "Questions that may already have your answer."**

Comment: +1 for the face drawing on the screenshot.

Comment: You can improved your proposal moving tag section right after title, so it's more clear for any users ?  +1 
Also +1 for "questions that may already have your answer"!

Comment: The only downside is that most users would add the tag after typing the question, and may have the wrong tag anyway: but it looks like an easy win, too good to pass up.

Comment: I agree with the tag positioning proposal. Placing it next to the title, either above or directly below it, would definitely help towards creating enough context for the criteria.

Answer (score 19):

I was actually going to suggest that we change the How to Ask page too, so I already have some ideas.

### Reiterating the rules

This has already been suggested in [several](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326919/6083675) [other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326882/6083675) [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326870/6083675), but I think it may be helpful to include a brief summary of the rules. In fact, this is one of those things that should be done on every site network wide because I have to spend a lot of time jugging tabs to know how to create a question on <some random site>.

To go further, if it's not enough to list the rules, we should consider detecting poor or problematic titles. Instead of blacklisting submission outright, early implementations could display a warning (and therefore allow data to be collected). If all goes well and it's accurate, then there should be no problem implementing a blacklist.

According to my research, there are some rules that off-topic questions  follow. [I've only explored recommendation questions so far](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280085), but I think that another easy target may be "no code included" debugging questions. It's a pretty good indication when there are words/phrases that indicate a debugging problem, but no code is present (note that "code" means different things in different languages: in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) it's going to be a block of code, but in [scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scratch) it should be a picture).

It might also be a good idea to prevent questions where the body is entirely a link, just a block of code, or it's identical to the title. In my experience, none of these are good questions (some of them may just need some editing).

---

### People ask a question to find answers, not other questions

It's obvious, I know. But for some reason, we decided to list the titles to similar questions, not the answers. Unfortunately, this requires the user to be active and click on the links, some of which may have a completely irrelevant title.

One of things that many people appreciate about Stack Overflow is how they can get answers to their question very fast. But what if you could get answers before you posted the question?

(Yes, I know that I'm describing "doing research". To be realistic/practical, we shouldn't expect that anyone will do this on their own, at least any more than they do now.)

It would need to be tested to optimize for UX, but imagine having another screen between drafting and posting the question where answers from similar questions are presented.

If one of the answers solves the problem, there should be a way to indicate that it helped, and then not post the question. If none of the answers work, then the user should be able to continue posting the question.

Like a hellban, it might be a convincing enough "surreal" experience that users don't need to actually continue and post their question.

This is similar (but not identical) to Ben Voigt's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326888/6083675).

---

### Better system for tags

People don't know how to tag. We need to display tag wikis/excerpts more prominently on the page (as has been suggested before). I also think that it would be fantastic if the community (or its mods) had the ability to change the tag blacklist (at least parts of it). We can decide to burninate a tag and have it disappear, but we are unable to do anything while it has [45,000+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) questions except watch as more question than can be edited are created with the tag.

Comment: +1 for the reforming the questions list. Not once have I ever asked a question and have seen anything useful there - to the point I don't even look anymore (admittedly). I'm sure it's just as easy for a newcomer to assert "my question is different" and not want to take the time to look through other answers.

Comment: Under "reiterating the rules", you seem to get into a digression about implementing machine learning to identify problematic questions. I believe I've commented about this before when you posted queues to identify recommendation questions based on keywords like "best". I don't really think this is a good idea. It sucks for the same reasons as obscenity filters, but even worse, because words like "best" are are just normal working words in the English language. A perfectly good programming question can use the word "best" and not simply be soliciting recommendations in an off-topic way.

Comment: I think we are best off focusing on ways to redesign the page to help people fall into the pit of success, rather than trying to implement complex algorithms to identify problematic wording. Obsessive focus on the "rules" is a problem as it is on Meta, with too many people voting to close questions because they have some or other keyword in them. Automating this process is not the way to go. Now, I think the reason this happens is we get so much crap that people are looking out for reasons to get rid of stuff, rather than looking out for ways to improve it. So we need to fix the core problem.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure you actually understand what I meant. That query I made was a very simple project, and it does not involve machine learning. You also missed the fact that my query requires two conditions to be met: it must contain a "target" (library, tool, etc.) in addition to one of the "trigger phrases" ("best", "open source", etc.). And AGAIN, it was intended to be somewhat overzealous in what it catches (it was made fr a different purpose, after all).

Comment: I approve the idea of serving up answers during the duplicate-checking portion of self-improvement.

Answer (score 13):

A lot of problems I see with new-user posts are code blocks (obviously not the *sole* problem, but bad code blocks tend to make questions look worse than they really are).

---

Firstly, can we bring in triple-tick code blocks?

```
Indenting pasted code is a pain...
```

`var theRest = "... and triple-tick blocks don't have proper formatting.";`

This is tricky for certain new users because most code review tools many users are familiar with (GitHub, Phabricator, Slack, etc.) use three ticks instead of indenting.

Further, indenting code requires highlighting it and hitting the `{}` (code) button in the editor, which I'd assume isn't directly apparent to certain users.

As well, if we adopted the ability to specify a language much like GitHub does, it'd benefit the experts as well since we wouldn't have to remember the weird `<!-- language: xyz --->` syntax in the event small code bits don't highlight correctly, which makes editing questions to correct such issues much easier.

---

Second, screen widths are not a problem anymore. CSS media queries exist, too. So why are we putting previews *below* the question input, *especially* since the user can re-size the question box? This causes the page length to grow at 2x the speed of typing.

I know this would have to be A/B tested, but I hypothesize being able to *always* see what you're typing *while* you type it would decrease the countless formatting problems new users seem to throw in there.

In the event the screen size doesn't adequately allow for a side-by-side view, use a media query to revert back to the old layout.

---

Third, we should be warning the user their issue may be the result of an indentation problem or a typo. We are a coding site, after all - services like [SourceGraph](https://sourcegraph.com/) can do it quite reliably.

This system could also be used to better enforce (warn) about [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)'s - or the lack thereof. **We have the technology** - we should be leveraging it!

Static analyzers/linters exist for every language out there, and even if the service on SE's end has them configured to only check a few things to trade for speed improvements, this would cut down a LOT of bad code blocks I've seen.

---

As I mentioned, code blocks aren't the only problem of course - however, in my experience, bad code blocks are indicative of bad questions, especially with new users. A lot - not all, but a lot - of the problems with said code blocks come from typos or things that linters could easily find, and we all know how impossible it is to help a user with bad coding examples.

StackOverflow is, after all, a coding site. If a question has poor English (as the case frequently is) but good code, it's generally still very answerable and the OP is generally quite happy and responsive to critique.

Most posters can read code better than human language, anyway - so let's allocate some focus on the code itself.

Comment: I don't really see how a linter is going to fix the problem with badly formatted code blocks. Are you hoping that if we run code blocks through lint first, it'll catch obvious bugs/typos and prevent those questions from ever getting posted? I don't think that'll help. Presumably the person is only posting the code as a question because they've run it through a compiler and the compiler barked at them. They don't understand what the error messages mean, or don't know how to fix them, so they've asked the question. (Agreed about your other points, though. A split-screen preview—like duh!)

Comment: @CodyGray Many linters point out that improper indentations may cause unexpected behavior. I understand it's not perfect, but it was just a thought. :)

Comment: Related: [Could Stack Overflow support GitHub flavored markdown?](/q/250157/1157100) and [Implement ```-style (fenced) Markdown code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125148/148099)

Answer (score 11):

When a new user clicks the `Ask a question` button, it would be useful
to recommend the user be prepared to stay on the site for 15 minutes
after posting the question in order to field questions asking for clarification.

This may improve the user experience for the new user -- they won't go away
expecting answers only to come back and find downvotes and their question
closed.  And it may reduce some frustration for answers who may be able to
answer the question if only they knew what the question was ;)

Asking a good question requires skills that can not be taught on a Ask
Question page. It requires experience -- multiple failures before one learns how
to get it right. Encouraging them to hang around for feedback increases the
likelihood their first experiences will be good ones that will help them acquire
the skill necessary to become good question askers.

---

If we define an "interaction" as an question where the OP leaves a comment within 15 minutes of posting the question, and if we define "success" as a question which receives an accepted answer, then we can use SEDE to investigate the effect of interaction on the chances of making a successful question:

Here are the SEDE queries:

- [SUCCESSES with OP interaction](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/510671/successes-with-op-interaction)
- [FAILURES with OP interaction](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/510672/failures-with-op-interaction)
- [TOTAL number of SUCCESSFUL questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/510674/total-number-of-successful-questions)
- [TOTAL number of FAILURES](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/510675/total-number-of-failures)

and here are the results:

```
|           | interaction |      total |
|-----------+-------------+------------|
| SUCCESSES |      794791 |    6605053 |
| FAILURES  |      569000 |    5412036 |
| total     |     1363791 |   12017089 |
| score     |  0.58278065 | 0.54963835 |
```

A chi-squared test suggests that this is a statistically significant result --
the p-value is << 1%:

```
# using Python
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
observed = np.array([794791, 569000], dtype=float)
N = observed.sum()
expected = np.array([6605053, 5412036], dtype=float)
expected /= expected.sum()
expected *= N
chisq, pval = stats.chisquare(observed, expected)
assert pval < 0.01
```

Thus, it looks like the chance that the OP receives and accepts an answer 
improves by about 3.3% if there is interaction within the first 15 minutes.

3% might not seem like much, but it is a quantifiable improvement and given the
billions of questions yet to be asked the difference will add up. Moreover,
given the simplicity of the change, why not?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your first paragraph. Yes, it is a good idea to be around to answer comments seeking clarification, but I don't think this is something we want to enshrine as an official guideline. **A question that needs clarificatory comments is *not [yet] a good question*.** That missing information should have been in the question itself. That's an idealistic view, I realize, and not going to be practical in many cases. But the hope is to design the Ask Question page to *minimize* the need for these comments (and downvotes and close votes), not to facilitate their taking place.

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with including this tip with the official guidelines.
It seems to me just a practical recognition that some users will need experience
(unlikely to be unobtainable on any Ask Question page) before they will be able
to pose good questions. It's *compatible* with other improvements to the Ask
Question page, not meant to supplant them.

Answer (score 8):

I also think some [kind of wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326873/4143855) would be useful. But I rather thought about the following:

1. the user types the question, and see an instant preview
2. the site asks: "what is your question about?", shows tag examples and explains that choosing the right tags is essential to getting the right audience, and thus a fast answer. Maybe it could even suggest tags based on the text of the question. It contain html snippets -> html. It contains a Java code sample -> java.
3. the site asks to summarize the question in a single sentence: that's the title of the question. It mentions that the title should not include the tags.
4. and this is the most important page to me. The site asks several questions, and forces the user to check a checkbox before going to the next question and finally be able to post:

   - here's the title of your question. If you were a random visitor of the site, willing to help, would you understand what your question is about? Check / No, I will change the title.
   - here are the tags of your question. If you were a random visitor of the site, willing to help, would you know which technology or subject your question is about? Check / No, I will change the tags.
   - here is the text of your question. If you were a random visitor of the site, willing to help, would you find your question well formatted? Are the code snippets correctly formatted and indented? Check / No, I will improve the formatting.
   - here is the text of your question. If you were a random visitor of the site, willing to help, would you find that your question contains all the necessary information needed to answer? Like for example, the relevant code and the complete and exact error messages needed to find the problem in your code? Check / No, I will improve the text.
   - OK, then. You can post your question.

Comment: [Encourage more meaningful titles by putting the title text box below the body of the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121806)

Comment: By "resume" I guess you mean "summarize" (or "restate")?

Comment: Anyway, the checklist before the question goes public is great, I just feel it's important to let them save their work before going through it.

Comment: I [edited your answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/326874/2) and added a link to [rene's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326873/4143855) mentioning the wizard, because I assume you were referencing it; however, if I was wrong and you weren't referring to it feel free to roll back my edit

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, that's what I meant. Confusion between English and French, where "résumer" means summarize.

Comment: Maybe switch the questions about tags and title, with an added remark like "don't repeat in  the title what you already specified in the tags"

Comment: @HansKesting done.

Comment: This is a good way to go in my opinion, the only issues I see with it is it is a very long tedious process.

Answer (score 8):

I think part of the problem is the little "How to ask" box in the sidebar, which currently reads:

> ### How to Ask
>
> **Is your question about programming?**
>
> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.
>
> If your question is about this website, **[ask it on meta instead.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)**
>
> [visit the help center »](https://stackoverflow.com/help)
>
>  [asking help »](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

I think this is a bit too vague, and *does not have the information people need*, and, especially in cases where there's a language barrier, is not clear enough.

Some rough, random ideas:

- The first bit - "*Is your question about programming?*" should be more explicit, that is, it should say something along the lines of "*Stack Overflow is for programming questions only*".

  Another problem is that this line fails to tell people that there are other Stack Exchange sites which would be more suitable for their question - I think it should say that there's other sites which might be suitable - such as "*Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, but [there's other Stack Exchange sites where your question would be welcome](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-name)*". I think this would help a lot in avoiding SuperUser questions on Stack Overflow. This would also be applicable to other sites, not just SO.
- The third bit - "*Provide details. Share your research.*" needs to be emphasized more, I think it should also be more explicit, something along the lines of "*Provide details. What exactly is the problem ? What is the error message ? What have you tried so far ?*", or similar.
- Regarding the last bit, about asking on Meta: how many people actually use this link ? Maybe it could be replaced with more relevant information if very few people use it.

---

The "How to format" box could also be made shorter and more concise, and perhaps that way, more people will actually read it.

- The sections on how to create italic, bold, bloquotes, code, and links could be replaced with just "*Select the text and click the relevant button*".
- The "How to make links" part shows *three* different ways to make a link - perhaps this can be shortened to just one ?

Comment: People don't read instructions. You could have the perfect "how to ask" box and it wouldn't make a difference IMO.

Comment: @BryanOakley That's undoubtedly true, probably 99% of the time. But SO is so big that 1% can actually make a difference, and if it costs pretty much nothing to make it better then why not?

Comment: How is that so many people who don't read instructions get the idea to come to Stack Overflow and ask stuff? I can only think of them either having done independent research in order to learn that there is such a website as Stack Overflow (in which case they demonstrate the ability in principle to do independent research); or else they were told about it (in which case they are following at least one instruction, which may they very well may have had to read).

Answer (score 7):

As a new user I can shed a little light on what I thought were some of the most difficult hurdles for me to overcome in doing something as simple as posting a question.

1. Formatting

   - I'm still struggling to get things looking neat.
   - It would be super helpful to see examples of how you should actually create a well formatted question.  By that I mean the actual text entered into the post box.
2. Finding the information I needed quickly and easily

   - Generally when I was to the point where I posted onto SO I was so frustrated with my problem that I just wanted to get my question out there.
   - I didn't want to spend an extra 10/15 minutes trying to learn how to get something on SO when if I was going to be researching the time should be spent on the actual problem
3. Knowing what a good quality question actually was

   - I never knew if my question was actual worthwhile or not until after I had posted it and gotten shot down/praised
   - It almost felt like a gamble posting a question?
4. Length Matters

   - I have posted a question that was very long (*too long*) and I've posted a question that was too short
   - it's been hard for me to find that perfect middle ground and having that information presented at posting would be awesome

Sometimes I see questions on here that seem like a valid question, but due to the improper formatting or asking the question in a silly way they get shot down pretty quickly.

These are just some things that I thought were issues and if improved/incorporated into the re-design would be really helpful to new users!

TL;DR I think that a more informative interface would help remedy the issues mentioned before.

Answer (score 4):

I like rene's suggestion and would like to add another facet: adaptive question-asking tips. I feel that SO is a gigantic ecosystem that is constantly shifting due to decisions on Meta. Understanding all of the finer details of what makes a question good, bad, subjective, objective, on-topic, belonging to another SE site, etc. is knowledge that is impossible to ingest on your first tour of SO as you are wanting to ask your first question. If we could rank all of SO's criteria of a good question from most important/most basic to least important/most nuanced, we could give different question-asking advice to users based on their question count and reputation. 
Example: for a new/low rep user, we initially ask them to make sure that their question is focused on one problem, is properly researched and has relevant code. As they gain experience on SO, we start showing them formatting tips, other SE sites that might be related to their question, or tips on writing a good title. Then, for experienced users, we might just give them links to meta posts that talk about good practices.

Bottom line: we can't create a perfect SO question-asker in 5 minutes, so let's focus on the meatiest bits first and give them an easy way to mature as they ask more questions.

Answer (score 4):

I think we should learn from Reddit here.

Just look at the [AskScience](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/) subreddit for example (or any subreddit).

They have all guidelines and every rules on the right side all the time informing the reader what should be posted there, and what shouldn't.

If you hover the mouse over the "ask science question" a red box pops up informing you that you should ask only if you read the guidelines. 
If you click on it, then yet another box informs you with huge letters that you should really read the guidelines before post.

I would like to see something like that on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I agree, I recall my first time posting on reddit went a whole lot smoother than my first times posting here because their guidance on the Ask page was a whole lot better. It's actually what I was thinking of when I wrote [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327028/302677) :)

Comment: At the point when we are using Reddit as an example of anything, we have failed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of the wizard idea, and think it would do a lot to help guide new users through the question-asking process.

At the same time, I'm a big fan of addressing the easy and obvious problems first, and I think there are some very easy-to-implement stop gaps that could be put in place to prevent a large number of low-quality questions from being asked in the first place.

Things like:

- Including a Code snippet that's longer than 20 lines
- Misspelling words, using incorrect capitalization, all caps, etc...
- Questions where links make up more than 10% of the question
- Questions where code snippets make up more than 70% of the question text
- Anything with less than ~200 characters of explanation text
- Anything with very poor grammar (Slightly harder, but very doable)

Other suggested heuristics:

- No question marks present
- No code present in question at all

I think that by having a short list of heuristics like these we could automatically recognize close to 50% of bad questions before they're asked and give people guided and direct feedback to facilitate changing it to be more appropriate.

I think that as a user goes through and asks their first couple of questions the need for these restrictions vanish, but I think that having these restrictions in place until a user asks ~5 questions or so would do a lot to solve the problem.

In my mind this is something like an MVP of the wizard. I think that having a full wizard is certainly the way to go in the long-run, but I think having a few heuristics here would be much easier to code and prototype in the short term, and could help to get some analytics around how much this helps the question-asking process before going to a full-on wizard.

Comment: * Any title or post that doesn't include at least one "?".

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils that feels a little less certain to me, looking at the SO homepage, I don't think the presence of a question mark is strongly indicative of question quality.

Comment: I'm attempting to deal with the questions that don't actually ask a question which is pretty common. It could improve quality possibly.

Comment: Another heuristic: Questions with no code at all.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Maybe questions without any questions marks?

Answer (score 2):

I'm inclined to agree with [Pekka's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326871/4994021).  What we really need to do is educate people, not force them through some wizard that will quickly irritate experienced users.  So how to do that properly?  I think looking back at school is a good source of inspiration...

The basic model to teach a new idea was:

1. Explain the principles to be applied.
2. Do some worked examples, showing how to apply them.
3. Give some further practice questions to build confidence.
4. Do some "real" tests, review the results and try to fill any gaps.

I think this could be applied as an online tutorial.  We already have the detailed advice on how to ask a question in the Help.  We could then hand pick some bad questions and explain how and why they were fixed (as Pekka has already suggested).

But then we could then move to an interactive section, challenging them to review what was wrong for some other examples.  This could be a multiple choice if we don't want to get into natural language processing, but there's some really clever people here...  Couldn't we do something a little smarter and ask them to fix up known errors?

At that point, they could ask their first real question.  As a final piece of guidance, we could do an automated critique for common errors.  In addition, some of the other suggestions already raised for fixing workflows could help here.

That just leaves the question of when to invoke this...  I would suggest either doing it for all users asking their first ever question, or after their first smack down.

Comment: The hard and unfortunate reality is that people don't want to be educated. They want answers. Coming to a site when your deadline is in 6 hours and having to go through a class just to ask your question is going to piss people off more than being led through asking the question they **really need** to ask.

Comment: The "wizard" proposals that I've seen are all limited to *new* users. Granted, these new users might be programming experts who are just new to our site, but then they would be equally unfamiliar with our unique model. After the first time you ask a well-received question, you wouldn't be subjected to the wizard. The reason people are suggesting the wizard is they think it serves both a practical and pedagogical purpose. It would take way too long to teach people all the theory/model of Stack Overflow. It's much easier to teach that *practically*, for a specific question, through a wizard.

Comment: @Qix The person who has never contributed before, can't be bothered to search existing Questions & Answers on Stack Overflow, but is in a rush for a quick solution to their problem while on their way off to Happy Hour is exactly the kind of user Stack Overflow does *not* need.

Comment: @BasilBourque what about users that *have* searched exhaustively and are still in a time crunch? If I could downvote a comment I would :P

Comment: @CodyGray I agree a pedagogical approach is required.  However, no wizard I've ever seen has really achieved this.  That said, rene's answer does try to be more than just a simple step-by-step process to fill in a form.  Speaking as someone who has to train developers, I find that people who "get it" need little help to figure stuff out for themselves, but people who don't need far more than some quick advice.  They need time, coaching and plenty of examples/experience to get their head around the probem.  I believe it's these latter people you're really trying to target.

Comment: @Peter Brittain: Computer games (e.g. the ["Dune" series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_%26_Conquer)) manage to do it without a wizard or manual. Perhaps some inspiration could come from there?

Answer (score 2):

### "My program does not work" Wizard

I've got inspired by the comment from  @MarounMaroun regarding the placeholders and templates.

We need a bunch of links on the first wizard page leading to wizards/templates that address common new user questons such as "My program does not work", "I get a compiler error", "My program crashes", "How do I do X in Y", "I expected a different output from my code","Please write my homework for me".

The beauty of this approach is that in a template we can *insist* on MCVE. We can ask for *exact* error text and even look it up on Google. We can even have a list of "Please write my homework for me" questions to show the new user what happens when they ask that kind of question.

The "My Program Does Not Work" wizard may be able to walk the user through steps to figure out if it's compile, link or runtime error. We could provide links to documentation. We could even explain the differenc ebetween compile-time and runtime error. The possibilities are endless!

Comment: *The beauty of this approach is that in a template we can insist on MCWE* not all questions need a **MCVE**

Comment: Any "My code does not compile" question does. In any case, if teh OP is sure, he can exit the wizard and go back to general "body" page. After viewing a list of choice questions that do lack MCVE.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think Arkadiy is proposing to force _all_ questions through this template -- only questions where the user indicates they have a compiler error/etc.

Comment: I was thinking that we provide links to those extra templates/wizards on the "Body" page, in a highly visible way. An honest new user should appreciate "My program does not work!" link that helps him in composing the question.

Answer (score 2):

If people actually read through the lists of "Questions that may already have your answer" and "Similar Questions", they'd ask far fewer duplicate questions. But those lists are easy to miss if you're not looking closely, and very easy to skip.

What if we put them on a separate page?

After you write and submit your question, you'd go to a new page that says "These questions may already have your answer." Below that would be a list of question titles, along with the opening text of each question. You would have to scroll down through them to get to the "Post my question" button at the bottom of the page.

Think of it as a detour that sends users along a path of Research before they reach the destination.

Comment: I'm wary of adding another interstitial, but +1 for showing the first few lines of the question. I sometimes use that list as an alternative to search, but having to open each question is annoying.  At least, it would make the list more useful for the users who already know to use it.

Comment: It would be good to show the first few lines of the "best" answers, too: If new users aren't extremely careful :-), they *might* accidentally get their answers before they get the chance to submit the question!

Comment: While there are many questions which can easily be marked as duplicates, *finding* the duplicate in the first place is often daunting, not least because the search functionality on Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange generally) is abysmal.  I find myself searcing in Google with `site:stackoverflow.com` works *much* better for me than using the on-site search. This has been brought up many times before in discussions about how to improve this aspect of asking, and there have been improvement projects, but ... this is still a problem which is a major blocker for this proposal.

Answer (score 2):

Three other ideas:

### 1. Whitelist

Use radio buttons (or a dropdown menu) to ask "What is the type of your question?"

- Specific programming problem
- Software algorithm
- Coding technique
- Software development tool
- Other

The user must choose an option before submitting. And if the choice is "Other", the user is shown a notice that explains what types of questions are on-topic.

### 2. Whitelist and sarcastic blacklist

Same options as above, but with additional options:

- Request for a product or service recommendation
- Request for someone's opinion
- Request for someone to write your code for you

Etc.

And if one of the "bad options" is chosen, the user is informed that such questions are off-topic for this site, and the question isn't posted.

### 3. Whitelist, blacklist, and questions for other Stack Exchange sites

Also include these options:

- General computing hardware and software
- Professional system and network administration
- Database administration

And a user who selects one of those options is told to post on Super User, Server Fault, or Database Administrators Stack Exchange respectively.

Making the user select an option would encourage more thinking before posting, educate users regarding what is on-topic, and maybe even filter out low-quality questions.

Comment: I think that list of what is considered on-topic has to be made far more detailed, and also with some examples of on-topic questions for each category. Anyway, I don't think the blacklist idea will work too well, because the people who ask crap questions would just click something random until they pass and then ask something entirely different anyway.

Comment: If they're (1) persistent enough to take extra steps, (2) obtuse enough to ask a type of question they've just been told not to ask, and (3) they don't care that their question isn't wanted. But many users are different. I've fielded plenty of questions from people who mean well but simply misunderstand Stack Overflow's purpose.

Comment: I like the Whitelist idea, and the questions for other SE sites, but I agree with @Lundin as far as the blacklist/sarcastic blacklist.  Users will just click until they find something that lets them click next.  The `Other` option might work.

Answer (score -1):

I see two big issues with questions. There are more, but these are the one I think the software can help with.

#### Policy Awareness

If there is any reference to policies on the "Ask" page, it needs to be configurable by site. Different sites have different rules, and different ways to express them. Many sites have elaborate how-tos on their Metas, for instance, a selection of which should be linked.

When should we show rules? Certainly for new users and users with a bad question track record. We may want to combine this with a (revised) low-quality-detector for new users; not *all* of them post bad questions.

Ideally, we would (in addition) be able to define regular expressions which trigger certain messages. For instance, if a user were to type `(how)? (can I|to) (show|prove|proof) \w* not context(-|\s+)free` on cs.SE I'd want to point them towards our reference material on this kind of (standard) exercise problem.

#### Tagging

Tagging is *horrible* from most new users. Almost every reasonable software support would be of help, such as

- suggest tags by matching words from body against tag descriptions and/or
- allow only the top 40 (?) tags for new (?) users.

What to do exactly is a whole discussion on its own so I won't elaborate here.

#### Low-quality detection

Okay, as I wrote the first section this came to mind. We already have low-quality detection; we should expand on that and warn users of potential problems *before* they commit the question. Criteria can be

- copy-pasting of large chunks but not not much else,
- few Markdown elements,
- almost only images,
- almost only links,
- almost exact copy of an existing question (possible in real-time?),
- title is similar to many other titles (possible in real-time?),
- no popular tag,
- tags that rarely appear together,

and many many more. If potentially problematic content is detected, the user should be informed as to which pitfalls they should make sure to avoid.
Discussion about this belongs in its own place as well, I guess.

Answer (score -5):

I think the root of the problem isn't the format and GUI of the question page, but rather the lack of intelligent scripts that block crap from getting posted.

Some examples of scripts that could be coded with very little effort:

- Does the question contain any question mark?
- Does the question contain sentences starting with "How", "Why", "What" etc but doesn't end with a question mark?
- Does the question contain sentences like "I need code", "give me the code"?

These are just examples of the most simple fixes. If investing time and effort, I'm sure people could come up with far more advanced scripts. I also think that such scripts already exist(?) but they are not very smart.

I think such scripts would weed out *lots* of bad questions, particularly if the site gave a vague response like "the ask a question button is for asking questions" or "questions asking for code written are discouraged on this site". The message shouldn't provide an easy way of bypassing the script, but instead force the poster to actually think.

---

The radical but likely more reliable alternative to smarter scripts would be to force every single first time post to pass peer review by high rep users. Might seem like lots of work, but I think that the other, present review queues would get massively reduced in favour of this new one.

Comment: My biggest concern with this is exactly what you said: these scripts "are not very smart." I'm sure that with some really smart programmers investing a lot of time, we could make them a lot smarter. But I'm not sure that's worth the time investment, and given how far behind we still are in AI relative to where we thought we'd be at this point, I'm not sure how smart we could even make them given high time and energy investment. Mainly, I worry that it would turn into an obscenity filter-type fiasco. And would it really force the user to think, or force them to think of ways to defeat it?

Comment: For example, [we currently filter out the word "problem" in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107989), which I think is a stupid idea. I see no compelling evidence that people have hit this and reworded their titles to be more effective. They just replace "problem" with "issue", or misspell it as "porblem", and hit submit. (Now you know why you see so many people who have "issue"s.) But I don't mean to dismiss all heuristics. There are currently several in place in the form of a rudimentary quality filter, but it still isn't turned up high enough to suit me.

Comment: @CodyGray They don't necessarily need to block submission outright, but in most cases a warning would be enough, something along the lines of "_Hey, your question contains a lot of spelling mistakes, do you want to go back and fix it ?_ [_Yes, take me back to the editor_] [_No, post as-is_]", and a message saying that crappy questions are less likely to get an answer.

Comment: How do you distinguish between "give me the code" and "Don't just give me the code -- I want to understand the algorithm"?

Comment: I don't support this because you don't have any evidence that this will help anything. I think that titles like `How to X` aren't problematic. I interpret it similar  to the title of a [How to guide](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-fix-the-most-common-imessage-problems-1577447675).

Comment: Upvoted for being the only answer that sets aside the problem of leading the horse to water and focuses on the more pressing issue of preventing the horse from soiling the water that other people are drinking from.

Comment: Isn't your last paragraph basically the Triage and First Post queues? Also, I agree that we should be blocking certain "crap" but we've already tried using regexes to solve the problem and have run into something akin to the [bad word filter problem](https://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/).

Comment: @Qix No! The difference is that this review would be done _before_ the crap hits the site. Means we don't have to see the crap, and the crap posters have to actually put in some effort to improve their posts.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I don't see how either sentence needs to be in a SO post.

Comment: @Lundin I like that idea a lot. As you mention it would be a lot of work, but it would also allow specialization. Some reviewers could focus on "keeping out low-quality questions while helping new users learn to ask better ones," while other reviewers do triage on non-first-posts.

Comment: Do you think that the decline in better questions is down to the dumbing down of society in general? I am surprised that half the people who ask questions actually know how to turn on a computer.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams That's one theory. On the other hand, it could be that society isn't any less smart than before, it's just that the Internet/web/social media are almost completely unfiltered compared to the media in previous decades.

Comment: @Lundin A bunch of other people have suggested "peer review new questions before posting" as well. It hasn't been implemented, though. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257858/should-we-peer-review-questions-before-publishing-them https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253286/why-not-peer-review-all-new-questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308481/can-first-posts-be-reviewed-before-being-becoming-visible-on-the-site

Comment: @jkdev At lot of people have suggested a lot of good things on meta, non of it implemented. The users hope to save the core of SO before its too late, while the SO staff focus on making "documentation", "teams" and unicorn games. It will be a surprise to them but not to me when the site suddenly collapses. The trend of experts leaving and quality declining has been going on for several years now. Right now I think the only thing needed to swiftly kill SO is to start up a similar site, with the very same concept, but higher quality focus.

Comment: Sounds good, but how does the new site avoid the same issues that contribute to the eventual doom of SO?

Comment: @jkdev By for example enforcing review of new user posts before their posts are allowed on the site :)

Comment: *"By for example enforcing review of new user posts before their posts are allowed on the site"* I expect it is not a coincidence that comp.lang.c++.moderated followed exactly the same model after the noise overwhelmed the signal in comp.lang.c++. It certainly does seem like a lot of work, though, and I'd first like to see if we can come up with a way to decrease the sheer volume of crap getting through in the first place. That would at least make subsequent review more palatable/possible.

Comment: @CodyGray Possibly smart scripts, wizards & guides etc first, to get the question in as good shape as possible, before passing it over to manual review. It's pretty obvious to me that something quite radical must be done. Making various cosmetic and/or pedagogical changes of the ask question page will achieve very little.