# Lets improve the model questions that are shown to new users before doing a dramatic redesign of other parts of the UI

Tags: discussion

There is a lot of excitement/activity around this particular question: [Let's improve Stack Overflow's "Ask a Question" page!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page).  I think it is a great question and the activity is great.

However, I think that one of the problems that leads to some of the questions that frustrate people is that many of the **model questions and highly upvoted questions** are not the type of questions the community is willing to accept when they show up on the site **today** from a new user (Reputation = 1).

Look at this question as well as the comments.

[How do I check whether a file exists using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-to-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python)

I want you to imagine your response to that question **if it appeared for the first time today**.  Also assume that none of the duplicates to that question existed either.

Look at the comments on this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079129/how-to-read-batch-part-of-txt-file-using-python#38079129

I know from my own experiences that learning to write a decent question is not easy.  And when I am writing a question I am dealing with my confusion and the tyranny of the urgent.  I am not writing code just for grins I have some bigger purpose in mind.  You have to expect that from a new user.  They are probably just learning to do amazing things and they have to get those things done immediately.

If I was struggling with trying to do something and finally found this site, poked around a bit and looked at some of the existing highly up-voted questions and this question ([Do Swift-based applications work on OS X 10.9/iOS 7 and lower?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-applications-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower)) I would be really confused, frustrated and disappointed by the responses I would get to my question.

I have to laugh, as I was writing this - here is the latest Python question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081869/beginner-coding-and-sticking-with-a-language.  Clearly even perfect models will not keep all the noise off the site.

I don't have a question here, I am just wondering if SO is presenting the right model questions to new users.

From the answer below *This is why there's so much interest in improving the Ask page: it's much, much easier for a question to do well when it states a problem clearly and in sufficient detail right from the start.*

I am not objecting to improving the Ask A Question page at all - please reread my first paragraph.  I am simply observing that there should be considerable care and thought put into the model/example questions.

We are a TechSmith client I am always impressed with the effort they put into understanding what their customers think when they look at web pages or when they look at their applications.  I think I have participated in 3 different sessions with their UI team and they ask very simple and direct questions about what **I think I am seeing** when I look at one of their products or pages.  They told me that they regularly try to hold sessions with customers who have a range of experiences with their products and find different issues with different customer classes.

Some of the comments below and the answer suggest to me that many of you do not understand what it is like to be a novice in this area.  If you want novices to use the site you expect them to use it correctly (as defined by the community) you have to provide good examples.  Good examples are not necessarily highly up-voted questions.

My analysis of the file exists question is that the try-except language is really what makes it a good question.  But if I were new to Python I would not understand that subtlety.

Comment: How is the "check whether a file exists in Python" a *model* question? Is there some special "model question" status that I've missed all this time? Are you just talking about questions with lots of upvotes?

Comment: It does say model and highly upvoted

Comment: I think this is a language issue - when people do something new they often look for a model, one model that would reasonably be used is highly up-voted questions.  If I came to a community and wanted to learn to fit in I would look for evidence of how others have succeeded.

Comment: I misunderstood your response to my question because "it" is a vague referent. If I ask a question about *your example* and you answer with "it", I'm going to think that you are referring to the example. You meant to refer to this question. Ok, so you do say "model question and highly upvoted questions" in your question. But saying "model question" is not useful unless both you and your readers understand what a "model question" is supposed to be. I would expect a model question to be more than just a question that was upvoted, otherwise it is redundant next to "highly upvoted questions".

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is that there are older, highly-upvoted questions which beginners see and expect that asking similar questions would be highly-upvoted. The problem is that the rules have changed since those older questions were asked, and thus they do not make a good "model" on which to base new questions. New users need to understand the rules *as they exist today*, not 6 years ago.

Comment: There's a bit of a differing opinion on whether or not the question you linked to is a good question. It is certainly on topic, and has proved to be VERY useful. there is no close reason that said question fits into, but people routinely mis-use too-broad to close such questions. Lack of effort isn't a reason to close vote, it's a reason to downvote.

Comment: **One of the simple things which could be done** is to show the editions short codes like those I recently found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments/24794#24794)... Would be great to have a link about this in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)...

Comment: If you click "help" next to the comment editor, or the question mark above the post editor, you'll get this same information and more @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: @Shog9: Lolll I really NEVER seen this link before! I just checked for the same thing in the question editor and there IS a small yellowish `?` icon too. Thanks! --- These links AREN'T visible enought then. Are they explained in the "tour" ?

Comment: Not directly; there is a link to the help center where a page lives under "our model".

Comment: @Shog9: I see... And this article look complete! Cool. **Suggestion**:  I would move it's link to the FIRST under "Asking"... And with a **bold title**. ;) Because I didn't see it... I have a good vision, I do not wear glasses! ;) I think MOST new users (under 1000pts) problably also didn't saw it. The vast majority of the `edits` I've made so far were "paragraphing and indenting". (I consider myself a new user, by the way ;) )

Comment: I should probably note that there's a HUGE "formatting help" sidebar on the editing page, with links to this as well @LouysPatriceBessette... Of course, it's in the place where ads normally live, so I suspect folks might be a bit blind to it.

Comment: You're absolutly right... Now that you tell me, I see it for the first time (lol). Yellow background makes it less attactive to the eye. This should be a modal popup for something like the first five questions.

Answer (score 4):

> Look at this question and the comments as well.
>
> [How to check whether a file exists using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-to-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python)
>
> I want you to imagine your response to that question if it appeared
>   for the first time today.

Well, my response would be to close it as a duplicate of the one that was asked 7 years ago. But hypothetical responses are boring; let's look at how folks responded to an *actual* question asked a year and a half ago:

[image: image of now-deleted question that was closed as a duplicate within a minute of being asked]

Oh. Closed as a duplicate, almost instantly. Well then.

It's notable that I had to look over a year back to find that; there are a bunch of *similar* questions asked more recently, but they tended to have some subtlety to them that made them *not duplicates*; some were well-received, others not so much. In short, having those simple questions asked and easily accessible means we usually *don't* have to deal with them being asked again and again and again... That part of the system works, but we don't think about it much because the pain it saves us is pain we never have to experience... If we hid them away, things would be much, much worse.

Note that your example seems to have suffered greatly *not* because it was simple, but because it lacked quite a lot of information in [the initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38079129/1). Once it was off to a bad start, folks just kept piling on.

This is why there's so much interest in improving the Ask page: it's much, much easier for a question to do well when it states a problem clearly and in sufficient detail *right from the start*.

Comment: I think you missed my point - pretend that question (and none of its duplicates) was asked for the first time today - keep all of the other history of SO in place except for that particular question (and the duplicates to that question)

Comment: Ok, look... You're pushing a very contrived situation. Why don't you instead examine questions concerning a newly-released platform of some sort? Those will be the closest thing to the scenario you're describing.

Comment: Okay but you are not a new user my point is a simple one - obviously you disagree and seem to believe that the model questions shown to new users do not encourage asking bad questions.  That is okay

Comment: They might. Then again, you're kinda assuming that new users are browsing top questions before asking new ones... Given most traffic comes in from Google searches, chances are that most new users are reading questions that align with the problems they're having, which are all over the map in terms of score and popularity.

Comment: Anyway, since you didn't try my exercise I went ahead and did it myself. React Native, a library for mobile dev using the React framework, was released about a year ago... [Here's one of the top questions, a one-liner similar to your 7-year-old example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289304/how-do-you-debug-react-native), the first question by a new user when it was asked: 35 upvotes, 0 downvotes, 13K views and a dozen answers.

Comment: This is why there's so much interest in improving the Ask page: it's much, much easier for a question to do well when it states a problem clearly and in sufficient detail right from the start. I don't disagree you must not have read my first sentence.  However, my point that it is should be more than a redesign of the path (UX) - the signposts along the path should also change (examples).  I personally do not think the react question is something that should be shown to a new user.   You have to decide who a first time user is.  Are they an expert like you or a novice like me.

Comment: Don't mean to be rude here, but... Let's try & separate personal preference from what's actually useful. That debugging question appears to have addressed a pressing need (info wasn't even in the docs yet) and collected a wealth of information... Objectively, it's an asset even if it doesn't match a form you or I would particularly want to show off. And the truth is, we could benefit from plenty of questions like that, *if they're not duplicates*. The biggest issue arises when folks *don't* read existing questions.

Comment: I am not sure about your comment - are you being rude - if so can I have your comment flagged?  A novice programmer is going to ask a different first question than an expert programmer.  My read of questions here is that the novices are the ones adding the most noise to the site.  I am not objecting to the React question being on SO I am trying to get you, an expert, to understand that me, a novice, would think that question would give me more license than I really have.

Comment: It's just a different kind of question. There's debugging questions, and then there's how do i do X questions. One requires code that doesn't work to be answerable, the other doesn't.