# How can I ask better "newbie" questions in a language I'm learning?

Tags: discussion

Back when I started JavaScript, my questions were often downvoted. As I got better, I figured out how to ask better questions because I was a little less clueless about the subject matter. Now that I'm trying a new scripting language, I'm back to being in that clueless phase, where even reading the docs is confusing for me, and my questions are getting downvoted again.

How can I ask "newbie" questions in a language I'm learning without being downvoted? For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337673/is-there-a-way-to-make-it-look-like-a-key-was-really-pressed-rather-than-just-in).

Comment: Sounds like you need to be spending more time doing research, reading through tutorials, buy a book, read articles, etc.

Comment: Newbies tend to assume that their problem is unique and never once experienced by other programmers that started to learn the language.  They are not often correct about that.  *Always* show what you did to solve the problem yourself and, if [the rubber ducky doesn't do its job](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) for some reason then you are much more likely to get an answer that is useful to you.  And others.

Comment: The vast majority of "newbie" questions I downvote is because the question is unanswerable as presented. This is usually one of 3 reasons: (1) No MCVE so I can't see/repro the problem, (2) bad assumptions leading to malformed question, (3) there was almost no effort put into asking/debugging before asking and a huge effort is required to answer.

Comment: (2) is especially annoying because quite often newbies are _convinced_ they know why the problem is occurring and will argue for their bad assumptions, even when they're completely ridiculous and make no sense. I often leave and never revisit questions when this happens.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say, don't search just once when you're looking something up.  Use synonyms, alternative terminology, different encapsulated (double quoted) phrases to explicitly find **exactly** what you're trying to learn.  Don't just search one time, then go to SO to get an answer.

Comment: @gravity When you're really new at something it's often one of the hardest things to know **what** to search for (in my experience at least). The solution is often to read a beginner's book of course but that's not really a good answer to questions ;-)

Comment: @AlexanderDerck - By the way - what are these `books` you all speak of?  :-)

Comment: @gravity They're ancient artifacts from the time SO didn't exist yet

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 is related to this.

Comment: @gravity [Bio-Optic Organized Knowledge](http://www.english.msstate.edu/undergrad/BOOK.html) is a revolutionary breakthrough in technology: no wires, no electric circuits, no batteries, nothing to be connected or switched on.

Comment: If you have a question on a relatively popular topic, ask it somewhere else. StackOverflow is completely packed with young males working hard at perfecting their grumpy old bastard skills. 

Back when dinosaurs roamed the earth, people realized that everybody was new once and not blessed with divine knowledge, and that it was OK to ask questions even if they weren't unique and unheard before by humans.

Also, I fully expect this comment to either vanish in a puff of smoke, or be downvoted or cast my account into hell or whatever other special powers the big users have.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short, sweet and to the point, when you have a question you don't know how to ask (a.k.a. a newbie question) it is usually better (per my experience) to talk to someone live ... either via Stack Exchange chat or IRC.

In terms of Q&A, information can be broken down into 3 parts:

- Things you know (the sky is blue)
- Things you know you don't know (the color variance of the levels of blue)
- Things you don't know you don't know (how heat affects the density of air thus causing different levels of blue)

If you know there are things that you *don't know that you don't know*, asking a few dumb questions in IRC will usualy lead to faster Ah-hah! moments which will lead to more valuable questions about *things you know you don't know*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_are_known_knowns

Comment: More relevant than @Two-BitAlchemist 's link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_competence

Answer (score 25):

There is nothing wrong with the premise of your question. The problem is in the ability to answer the question.

The main problem statement in your question is

> the game isn't taking the value inputs as keyboard presses - it isn't triggering the abilities in the game

However, as a potential answerer, there is no information to use in your question in order to determine how the game is working with the inputs aside from the simply repeated code from your previous post.

The reason that [MCVE's](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are preferred to plain examples is that it allows for the whole picture to be presented. Had your question actually been answerable, I am confident it would have generated an answer and a better reception.

In its current state, I just don't see how someone could possible show the solution to the game taking value inputs and triggering abilities with the given information.

Comment: i see.. It was my assumption that there might be some way in that language to differentiate between inputting a value and triggering a key, regardless of how the game is working with the input. Maybe the solution wouldnt work with the game, but if there's a way to make the key look pressed to the system - if thats possible in the language - thats what I was interested in.

Comment: @Viziionary then that's what you should have asked

Comment: @Viziionary Another newbie mistake: Asking to "Fix my code" instead of just asking about the *underlying concept* that they are confused about.

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR version**:

1. Learn from others (book, course, in person or online)
2. Ask on google / search engines
3. Ask on StackOverflow

**Long answer**:

Don't default your learning approach to trial and error, especially if you have zero knowledge on the subject. Instead, buy a book or an online course, go through it.

Be prepared to spend money. Paid is usually better than free, often by a lot. Do your research though and don't buy because it's paid or expensive. Learn how other people do work in this language / subject matter.

Don't default to "I'm smart, I got it". Feel comfortable, see how you can apply what you learned, start improving beyond that by using google and trial / error also. Then if you have questions - feel free to ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: The OP says "even reading the docs is confusing for me" which implies he's already doing #1.  "My questions are getting downvoted again" shows that he's already doing #3.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson: Docs are often confusing and sometimes misleading. Unfortunately, great documentation is very expensive to maintain and most companies cut corners. It's much better to initially get structured knowledge from a reliable source. Docs are good for cases when you forgot a small piece. I hope no-one believes they can learn to program by reading MSDN.

Comment: I took "Docs" to include the "books" you suggested, and vice-versa. If you meant manuals other than the limited ones the OP was probably currently using, then, well, yeah.

Answer (score 7):

> How can I ask "newbie" questions in a language I'm learning without being downvoted? For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337673/is-there-a-way-to-make-it-look-like-a-key-was-really-pressed-rather-than-just-in).

**General advice:**

Stack Overflow isn't so much about keeping beginner questions for *learning a language*, also you are missing a particular language tag on your question.

In most of such cases you should have done some research before asking a new question, and you're likely asking a duplicate.

Comment: On the purpose of Stack Overflow, I couldn't disagree with you more.  Anyone that can ask a proper answerable question can ask it.  Your attitude is elitist.  You should consider that everyone starts at the beginning at one point in their lives.

Comment: @Brad _"Your attitude is elitist."_ No, I'm just thinking from a more long term view, what SO should be about IMO. And as mentioned _beginner questions_ are mostly duplicates (that's at least observable from my preferred language tag, which is [tag:c++]). And what's actually wrong answering with your personal observations for such questions on meta?

Comment: Duplicate questions occur at any level.  Sometimes people can't find what they're looking for.  Other times they don't search.  Close the question as a duplicate.  New questions don't need special treatment.

Comment: @Brad _"Close the question as a duplicate."_ Well, that's what I'm doing frequently, especially as a gold badge holder for my preferred language tag.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a really important and critical topic that StackExchange should put effort into addressing.  I try to help newbies by formatting questions, asking clarifying questions, etc.  But whether there are language barriers, understanding of what the site is for and how it works, etc.

Perhaps there should be a higher barrier to entry for people to *ask* questions until they have demonstrated sufficient understanding to do so.

All of us are ignorant at the start, but the tone on SO and others is devolving over time to be dismissive and exclusionary.  This is not helpful for anyone -- even a down vote is a harsh and unwelcoming response.  Some people are lazy and pasting in the question from their homework.  Others may not have read the requirements for a valid question.  Many are new developers who are still trying to figure out what their boss just asked them to do.  Without knowing the language of engineering, people will not likely have the words to ask really well.

The people who are not asking "right" are either people who will never do so, or people who can be great members of the community if we guide them on gently.  Perhaps until a user gets an up-voted question they are forced to prove they have done the things needed to ask correctly?  Maybe there's a new reviewer queue for newbie questions?  Maybe there's a required tutorial or test.

If anyone has any doubt that SO is being undermined by terrible quality questions, take a look at the top 10 latest questions on any keyword -- most from first-timers, most poorly formed, most not formatted, etc.

Comment: "but the tone on SO and others is devolving over time to be dismissive and exclusionary"... [People were saying that 2 years ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late). I don't think it's any worse now than it was then. The thrust of this question sounds quite similar to [suggestions on another question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326868/215552). Might be something to look into...

Comment: Yes you're right, not worse than a couple years ago -- maybe it's just getting more irritating to me :-).

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that doing your own research, trying to figure it out yourself, and making [minimal, complete, and verifiable examples (MVCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are important and should definitely be encouraged, I also think that some "newbie" questions should be given a greater tolerance.

**Researching the answer**

If it is an easy question but an easy Google search (using the vocabulary of the asker) doesn't give an answer, then allowing this type of question (marking as a duplicate if necessary but not downvoting) will make it easier for future newbies to find the answer in the future. Sometimes newbies just don't have the right vocabulary yet to find what they are looking for.

I think oldies forget how hard it is to understand the documentation when just starting out. It is also unhelpful to tell people to go take a class when all they want is a simple answer for a simple question that a simple search didn't reveal.

**Creating an MVCE**

For newbies in a language, it is sometimes not possible to create a complete example. One can only describe the task one is trying to achieve. I can't tell you how much I loved some of those simple "newbie" questions when I was starting out in Android and iOS. There was no MVCE. I did a simple Google search and got a simple Stack Overflow answer. In my opinion, these type of questions are still useful.

**Conclusion**

I know that a lot of oldies disagree with my opinions above. I also know that a lot of junk from newbies comes in. I'm just saying that a certain class of newbie question should be given more tolerance.

Comment: "I did one google search and looked at the first result" is simply not a suitable standard of research.  And when you answer questions that are already readily available you're *not* improving the searching of other people that actually do their research as the information will have already been readily available; having 100,001 google results instead of 100,000 isn't a relevant change.

Comment: If the entire first page of Google search results only return general documentation or long tutorial style results for a specific search question with good key words, then I think that question deserves a place on Stack Overflow. If it is a duplicate of another question that used other key words then mark it as a duplicate. But in my opinion it is still a helpful question and not worthy of a downvote.

Comment: People shouldn't just be ignoring all non-SO sources of information.  If the top result is a relevant section of the documentation that answers the relevant quesiton, then people should be reading it and letting it solve their problem, rather than having an SO user tell them what that top google result would have told them if they bothered to read it.  SO isn't here to just duplicate all of the information in every language's documentation, as well as all of the programming information in every tutorial/article/etc.  It's there to supplement what those sources *don't cover*.

Comment: @Servy, I agree with you when that information is readily available on other sites. However, when I have a very specific question and I get a list of blogs, documentation, and Stack Overflow questions, I almost always choose SO first. It is usually the fastest way to the answer. When there is no SO question/answer, I often have to spend considerably longer reading through more general topics that only tangentially answer my question.

Comment: And yet by actively encouraging people to flood SO with thousands of posts a day of questions trivially solved with a simple web search, you drive away subject matter experts and anyone who'd be able to answer a question *not* trivially answered with a simple web search.  By helping people avoid 45 seconds of research (by spending 10 or more times as long writing an SO question instead) it continues to move SO to a place that won't be able to do anything *but* that.

Comment: @Servy, You have a good point there.