# A special markup for error messages

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

The idea is so surprisingly obvious that I can't believe no one suggested it yet.

Stack Overflow is a SE-based site for programmers, you know. And programming errors is the main reason why people come to ask a question. Yet there is no special markup code for the error message, and people are trying to format it either as a code or a citation while neither is really satisfying: for example, code formatting often makes one-line error message go off screen and citation is parsing all the markdown special characters, spoiling the text.

The most interesting part: **Knowing the error message, the related questions mechanism can start offering relevant suggestions** instead of that garbage it suggests at the moment based on the title which is "I am writing an android app".

With some effort on the developers' part (including some snoop-and-suggest technique and encouraging banners) this feature can dramatically improve the efficiency of this site.

Update.
An even better suggestion from Glorfindel in the comments - a special field in the question form. Remember - Stack Overflow is a very special SE site related to programming and thus having such a dedicated input field makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Why is citing error message or error stack trace in code block wrong in your opinion? Personally I think Error messages look more natural and easier to read in code blocks.

Comment: A separate input field `Paste your stack trace here`?

Comment: @NSNoob The go off screen, you know

Comment: @Glorfindel that's damn even better! A special field for the error message and an alert, "Are you sure you want to left it blank?"

Comment: So does code, many times. Scrolling a bit doesn't really hurt Compared to when alternative is citation block which many times messes up the real outlook of the error message (Making strings with ** bold etc). Anyways guess that's not the point of this post so I'll shut up :D

Comment: @NSNoob the code is *usually* formatted to fit the screen. The error message is *usually* a one line. "citation block which many times messes up the real outlook of the error message" - **so that's the damn point of my request.**

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326868/4751173) is related question about improving the Ask A Question page, which include ideas about having some kind of templates instead of a 'free-format' question like we have now.

Comment: @Cerbrus surely you read the question body, not only title, aren't you?

Comment: _"The idea is so surprisingly obvious that I can't believe no one suggested it yet."_ Because people ___have___ suggested it. Even SO's own search for _"format output"_ returns dupes.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: _"Yet there is no special formatting code for the error messages"_ <-- That's your feature request, right?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: That's not very constructive. The title, first 2 paragraphs, and last paragraphs are all about a better way to display error messages. There's only ___one___ paragraph that's clearly talking about some kind of search improvement, then there's one that talks about "This feature". Excuse me for mis-interpreting this question, as it's obviously not about 80% of what's in there.

Comment: @Cerbrus You know the "questions that may already have your answer" list that tries to pick terms from the partial question?  YCS's point is that if there's special markup for (or even a separate input box for) error messages, that search will be able to weight that information highly in looking for duplicates, because the markup would then describe the semantics of the text.  About the _markup_, not the rendering.  (Though I agree that "formatting" in the title is a bit misleading.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: I get what he's trying to suggest, but this question, ___as is___, is a duplicate. It should either be closed or _completely_ re-written. In it's current state, the question just isn't clearly about what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: I feel @Glorfindel's suggestion should be a feature-request on its own. I'd rather not add another type of markdown, but separate fields for stack traces and error messages could be very useful.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom thank you, I fixed the wording.

Comment: *"Stack Overflow is a very special SE site related to programming and thus having such a dedicated input field makes a lot of sense."* Only if you want to further encourage "debug-my-code" questions. Not sure about you, but I certainly don't. There are lots of good, interesting questions that do *not* have an applicable "error messages", and integrating this into the question submission page would send absolutely the wrong message. We are not HireACoder.com.

Comment: Even after the edit, the question still appears to be about adding some kind of markup for error messages, primarily.

Comment: @CodyGray "debug my code for me" is a question that essentially **doesn't contain an error message** but just a blob of code. My aim is to make this site helpful for the programmers, and better search for error messages is for that. Besides, it's too naive thinking that lack of such a field will make *any* difference. SO is *already* a fix-my-code site. So the choice actually is between keep it as is or improve. And yes, if your question is good and without an error message you may just leave thet field empty. Not a problem.

Comment: Well, okay. Maybe "debug my code" for me is the wrong aphorism. The error message already did the debugging, so you end up with "write-my-code-for-me". It is not clear how this is better. Certainly it is easier to write answers to these types of questions when the error messages are available, but the people who write these kinds of crappy questions that omit the error code probably aren't going to magically start writing better questions just because we throw another text box at them. And the people who *are* conscientious and *do* care will get the wrong idea if we appear to demand one.

Comment: @CodyGray thank you. You made me realize that my devotion to SO is insane and rather ridiculed by the community. So after thinking soberly I decided to drop out from a duty I chose for myself some time ago. You are right, it doesn't matter, whether a question is good or bad or a duplicate. Nobody cares. So shouldn't I. Buried my Mjollnir forever.

Comment: I...uh...I didn't say that. And I *certainly* don't agree with that spirit, so do not misconstrue my comments as an endorsement of that position. I care a *lot* about quality, close bunches of questions, and downvote often. Do note that engaging in these actions actually helps to solve the problem because it pushes chronically bad contributors closer to an automatic ban, so it's not quite as much shoveling shit uphill as you might assume. You are, of course, free to do as you wish.