# An easy way for a beginner to know what topics he or she can ask on the Stack Overflow site

Tags: feature-request, scope, user-experience

I know where are the instructions of [what topics can I ask about in Stack Overflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, I had trouble finding this information. I needed to search it on Google and only then I found out that the information was within the small Help link in the footer of the site.

I think this information should be more visible and easy to find on the homepage. While I was looking for it, I expected to find the info at the top of the site, near the logo.

It's just my feedback. Maybe I'm wrong. But I wanted to describe the bad user experience I had, because maybe it's happening to other users as well.

---

**The context of my experience:**

1. It had been a long time since I registered with Stack Overflow. I did not even remember there was a Tour.
2. I did not know the rules very well. I just knew I could ask about programming.
3. So I asked a question about how to improve my code. Immediately somebody down-voted my question and informed me that I should ask that question in the "Code Review" StackExchange site.
4. Because of that I started to look for information about the rules of what I could and couldn't ask. I thought that this information would be directly related to the definition and purpose of Stack Overflow. Since most of the existing sites on the web bring their definition and purpose prominently on the homepage, I accessed stackoverflow.com in the hope of seeing this information.
5. As I was logged in, that didn't work. I didn't have the idea of logging out at that point. I only thought of this later, when I had already found the information I wanted. Anyway, this wouldn't help at all.
6. Finally I gave up looking inside Stack Overflow site and went to Google search. Only then did I find the information I wanted.

---

**Screenshot of Stack Overflow when I'm logged in:**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Honestly, I'd tend to agree with you on this. While if you click around a bit you'll eventually find the link to the help center, I think it should be more visible and clearly labeled like the "Questions" or "Users" links. The help center is one of the first place every user should visit when first coming to the site, so it should be easy to find. _OTOH_, if you've taken the tour, there's a very visible link to the help center right at the end. But I still think it'd be nice to have redundancy.

Comment: before the change in the header (as you can see with other sites) you could just click on the help button at the top and go to [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or the help center. before the footer change the tour was in there even on SO but now it's gone

Comment: Note that *all* new users see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) before they can ask a question. This is a pretty decent page, but also very very hidden; I had to search my old comments to find the link. IMHO that page – or something like it – deserves some liberal linking across the site.

Comment: There's also the Help Center link under "How to Ask" when you actually go to ask a question and new users are encouraged to take the Tour, which also links to Help Center articles at the end. Is the issue that you couldn't find the help link at all or that you didn't know the information you wanted was in the help link?

Comment: @BSMP The latter option. The problem is that I was not looking for a Help link. I wouldn't have imagined that I should have to access a help link to get that information.Maybe my eyes went through the link but I just ignored it unconsciously. Also, I was not asking a question, so the Help Center link under "How to Ask" does not apply in this case. (I will edit my question to include more details about the context in which I was looking for the information).

Comment: Note: Even if I were asking a question, I think I would not have noticed the Help Center link when looking for the information, since the link is inside a "How to Ask" box, and not a "What to Ask" box. It would be better if the title were "How and What to Ask".

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your header bar? I recall I was using many times that old nice "?" button. With new UI it's gone for me, I really miss it and if it's missing for you too - then it's a big big fail.

Comment: Do note that you can get to help by clicking on the site switcher: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnxUv.png

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, because the list of all of the different sites on the network is obviously the logical place to go to figure out what the appropriate code of conduct is for the site that you're on...

Comment: @Servy It is logical, but IMHO it is not intuitive. To be honest, I never had the curiosity of clicking on that button, so I didn't know what was it for. I will start using it now :)

Comment: @viniciussss I don't see how it's logical at all.   The help center for the current site has no place in a tool designed to help you find and access other sites on the network.  If the help center can't be found by people actively looking for it, then it's not doing its job. It's hard enough to get people to care enough to want to read the site's rules, but to actively inhibit people from getting to them when they *want* to is just bad.

Comment: strongly related: [Ways to give users some specific education about question quality and topicality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277607/165773) and [Usability issues for first-time Stack Exchange users - a micro-study](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279661/165773)

Comment: Ask a terrible question and you'll get 'help-linked' pretty quickly :D

Comment: @C-PoundGuru Well that's the thing, the OP *did* ask an off topic question and got told it was off topic in the comments but the commentor didn't actually point them to the Help Center. This might also have been due to the OP having 800+ rep but a user commenting that something is off topic without a help link is pretty common.

Comment: @carpetsmoker - seeing a page and being forced to read a page for comprehension and prove you comprehended are not the same thing

Answer (score 12):

**My suggestion to change the yellow box in the Asking page:**

I think it would help.

[image]

**"How to ask"** link would refer to: [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

**"What kind of questions to as in this site"** link would refer to: [stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I agree some kind of more prominent feature might help stop the flood of close worthy questions. It certainly seems worth a shot. Heck, I'd consider trying make it so until you have 250-500 points, every time you ask a question you're required to manually type in some popup "I have read what kinds of questions are on topic for stack overflow and I promise my question is on topic" including adding some JS so can't paste in the text, it must be typed). I'm serious that if it was up to me I'd at least A/B test something like that. For the next 1000 points it can change to a checkbox.

Comment: One time, [this dude proposed improving the Ask page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page), but…crickets. Obviously no one on the team cares about this anymore. But hey—we got a new top nav, a new footer, and new shades of green in the profile page!

Comment: [Rachel's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327028/4077150) (for the question Cody Gary linked for) is much better than mine.

Answer (score -6):

I think this question is based on a flawed premise of; *"new users seek out this information on their own "*. This is demonstrably not the general case. They usually need to be beat over the head with it and still willfully ignore it.

Get the [auto-comment plugin](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) and use it, no one can claim ignorance anymore when you use this and it is little effort.

Here is my [personal most useful comments](https://gist.github.com/jarrodhroberson/aec6428bfdc792659c250d854df9e16a).

Lets you effortless post a comment with the relevant information:

> Please read [What types of questions should I avoid
>   asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to
>   ask more questions.

Comment: How is this an answer to "An easy way for a beginner to know what topics he or she can ask on the Stack Overflow site"? Did you post it on the wrong question?

Comment: Lets you comment, in two clicks -> Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: So your answer to "An easy way for a beginner to know what topics he or she can ask on the Stack Overflow site" is that they should post it anyway and wait for someone using the auto commenting plugin to tell them afterwards it was off topic?