# Can we help new users that are new in the technology?

Tags: discussion

In the past few days I've been trying to help in the First posts review queue https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts and noticed that among questions that admit "I am new in XYZ technology" there is literally zero that can be reasonably answered on this site. Almost always the question is too broad ("how do I do ABC in XYZ") there is no MCVE etc.

Is your experience similar to mine?

I hope I am able to use the right tools available in the review queue every time. My question is aimed at the users themselves: how can we help them?

Perhaps something like this? If we detect the combination "new user + text contains 'I am new at'" we recommend some tutorials first?...

Comment: We could create a help center, add guides about how to ask good questions and ask new users to sign off that they've read them?

Comment: Whatever the technology you are new at, and we are always new at something; you are only one web-search away from getting more knowledge. SO shouldn't be in the business of recommending external tutorials.

Comment: @ivarni _sign off that they've read them_ I actually really like that idea, of course they could just click the "next/agree" button but I think the issue is a lot of users haven't even seen the help pages, at least this way they couldn't claim ignorance

Comment: Do we really *need* to help people who can't be bothered to Google `<name of technology> tutorials` or `<name of technology> first steps`?

Comment: @Pekka웃 good point, so can we get rid of them faster? :)

Comment: Yeah, many of us would like to :) But that's an ages-old conflict around here... where to draw the line, what to do with users who cross the line, how to not make the place a BOFH hellhole in the process, etc. There is the question banning algorithm that does a *lot* of work.

Comment: @Pekka웃 you tell me now that BOFH is **NOT** our guide book? I need to adapt some responses then ...

Comment: @George: ivarni was being sarcastic. New users are already asked to sign off that they read the help information. They still claim ignorance.

Comment: related: [An easy way for a beginner to know what topics he or she can ask on the Stack Overflow site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351495/839601)

Comment: @MartijnPieters But are they actually shown the pages or just asked if they've read them?

Comment: @George: they are redirected to the How to Ask page first. See [New users should guess why they can't proceed to asking their first question... not the best experience](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/177028) for a description of what happens.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, it's good to know. Can't say I remember the sign up very well after ~5 years :)

Comment: I cannot think of anything that can be done for such OP's.  Many are 'new in XYZ technology' because the are 'new in any software technology' and, well, cannot program computers.  If you filter out such phrases and redirect them to a tutorial/textbook list, they will stop putting those phrases in the question to ensure their Q gets posted, (or click through, as already suggested).  If they wanted to do the work of reading books and running tutorials,. they would have done it already.  Let them post, close their Q immediate, and ignore the meta posts re. 'unfair downvotes for newbies',

Comment: @MartinJames what automated tools can help us with this? How about the question banning algorithm?

Comment: In meaning well we're really experts at making things worse. Stack Overflow is not a great environment for true novices, because they lack the experience to form good enough quality questions. Tutorials however are even worse than Stack Overflow. The average tutorial is an instruction list; "do this, do that, good luck if it doesn't work in your version". What is needed is an instruction guide; do this BECAUSE. Don't do that BECAUSE. In other words: the why, not the how. Definitely hard to find such material online as a free resource, people might have some success on a site such as Reddit.

Comment: @vektor I don't know the details of whatever automation currently exists, but I do know that it's very difficult to develop a 'Garbage Detector' that would be acceptable for the site.  SO does not want any barriers to new users, even if many of them are gimme teh codez, one-account-per-question deadbeats, homework copypastas, puppets or voting ring members.

Comment: Sadly, @Gimby is right.  My experience with 'Intro to X' sites is pretty bad too:(

Comment: Creating a tutorial that covers more than the "happy path" is a _lot_ of work. You can find such things in books, because someone producing such a thing will want to be paid for the time it takes her. So the problem is how to convince everyone that they probably _can't_ learn to program from Stack Overflow: they still, even in this wondrous modern age, need a book and probably a mentor/tutor.

Comment: This is *why* books are written and schools charge tuition -- teaching well takes time, energy and expertise, and as many have mentioned, is beyond the purview of this site. My recommendation to newbies is to go out and buy a bunch of ***used*** books on their subject of interest. Used books are cheaper, and while they may be somewhat out of date, they can gain the student enough knowledge to push them over the steep newbie potential energy barrier so that this site and online tutorials *can* help them.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That'd basically be the problem; Stack Overflow has replaced books as the go-to thing. And before that the web in general did. "Why would I buy books when I have access to the internet?" But the basic premise of this question is how we could direct users to such valuable sources - unfortunately we're not too fond of book recommendation canonicals either.

Comment: @Gimby: To allow this site to make these recommendations would be to change one of the main tenets of the site. Yes this can be done, but *should* it be done? Currently we close the off-topic question, oftentimes leaving a comment as to why its off topic, and sometimes with one of these recommendations thrown in. Does it satisfy the poster? Usually not. Should it satisfy them? Usually not.