# What should a new user do instead of posting "I have the same problem"

Tags: discussion, questions

Having recently gained access to the Low Quality Posts review queue, I'm seeing a lot of answers with *Did you find a solution yet? I'm having the same problem*

I obviously recommend deletion on them, but I started wondering what approach should a new user take if he has the exact same problem, and the question is well-written?

Assuming a new user with not enough reputation to put a bounty on the question, he could create a new (identical) question, but it would probably be closed as a duplicate.

**What approach should a new user take in this case?**

Comment: They should get enough reputation and comment instead.

Comment: If the original doesn't have an answer, then it can't be used as a duplicate target.

Comment: @Albzi
That's very much not-user-friendly. We're supposed to be a community, not a set of elitists.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately that's how the system works. It's also why I didn't post it as an answer and left it as a comment, as I knew there would be better options than that. @GeorgeWL

Comment: Also upvote the question.

Comment: There are _a lot_ that are like this. You will soon get tired of trying to help each user out. It's nice that you're one of those guys though that _wants_ to help.

Comment: @GeorgeWL Preventing spam isn't elitism.

Comment: whilst true @bsmp you do get some people treating young users with an unwarranted disdain and impoliteness.

Comment: @GeorgeWL That still doesn't make the rule itself elitist.

Comment: "I have the same problem" is not a useful comment, either, @Albzi.

Comment: Very valid point. Again, this is why I didn't post it as an answer because I knew that it was not the best course of action! Maybe I should remove my top comment as it gives the wrong impression? @CodyGray

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They should ask a question...

That question should start with a link to the question(s) that apparently describe their problem and then elaborate which answer(s) they tried, what the outcome was and how that didn't solve the problem for their specific context (which they should describe as well).

By doing all that:

- they prevent their question being closed as a duplicate
- due to the linking of questions potential answerers can rule out certain solutions
- future visitors will find their and the linked questions

If they picked a question without answers then they are less lucky but should still try to formulate their question and share their research in such a way it is better and different enough to not qualify as a duplicate (despite that their question can't be dupe voted).

Stating *I'm having the same problem* where none of the current answers will work is more likely to mean: *I don't fully understand yet why in my context I get the same error but none of the answers solve my issue*. That should be a signal for them to work on a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I feel like this would be great to have as part of the placeholder text for new posts actually, or something rather similar.

Comment: Or, like, we could [make it an option when we redesign the Ask Question page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page)!

Comment: It looks the redesign of that page slipped by a couple of 6 to 8 weeks ....