# What about detecting "minimal reproducible example"?

Tags: feature-request

I have been answering questions on SO since July. What I see is that new questions are mostly newcomers'.

Most of these newcomers don't know what a minimal reproducible example is and so the question is often really difficult to answer. Basically, the first comment is something like "Please provide a reproducible example" with a link to one of the great posts to how make one.

So, I wondered if it could be a good idea to make this minimal reproducible example mandatory in order to post a question. I'll explain how.

Generally, when I post a question myself, one of the first lines of my question is "My reproducible example is:". **What if a bot could detect for these keywords and make them mandatory for a newcomer (or everyone) in order to post a question?** This way, everyone would have to know what a minimal reproducible example is before posting.

Thoughts?

Comment: The kind of people that have the mindset that people can magically see their screen/read their mind or otherwise crystal ball debug their code or will just dump everything anyway won't be deterred they'd just `/* ignore this code block - stupid system wouldn't let me post this comment without it apparently!!! */; int i = 0; // need to make this line a bit longer` type any out rubbish until the system lets them post.

Comment: The problem is, not all questions require a reproducible example, so this is not something that we could pre-filter for. Also, what Jon said: some people are incorrigible and cannot be helped.

Answer (score 10):

> What if a bot could detect for these keywords and make them mandatory for a newcomer (or everyone) in order to post a question?

Let's ignore for the moment how easy it is to game such a system. Let's focus on the best case scenario: that everyone provides an example.

What if the "newcomer (or everyone)" isn't asking a question about broken code? What if they're asking about how an API works? Or what the meaning of a particular set of function calls is? Those are perfectly valid questions on this site, after all. Your suggestion would effectively ban them.

Indeed, I personally find such questions to be far more interesting than "something's wrong with my code" questions.

Comment: Yeap, you're right. I was biased by the questions I usually answer.

Answer (score 2):

A reproducible example is always desirable, but I've found myself in situations where it's just not possible (usually because the end user wouldn't have the same conditions, for example when you deal with [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) generated projects or the project is that huge you just can't control the way it is configured). So it wouldn't be useful to have a bot checking for this, instead I would find it handy to have some kind of default text determining the desirable question format, the way Github allows:

[image]

Comment: Considering how often I see _"enter code here"_ in questions: Followed by 50% of the new users also posting that template.

Comment: See also: [Let's improve Stack Overflow's "Ask a question" page!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326868)