# Is there a way one can display hints to people asking their first question on a particular topic, say pandas (python)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I relatively frequently visit the new questions tab of the #pandas tag and very often the first comments on someone's first question will be something pointing to the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page. Most newcomers don't know [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and as a result the answering of the question is delayed unnecessarily, especially because the mcve page is too abstract for most newcomers and they don't know how to use .to_dict() for making a copy of their example DataFrame.

If the question contains links to images, most of the time there is no mcve, so a standard answer should be displayed instead of community members having to re-type the same comment over and over again.

I realize that the question [What about detecting "minimal reproducible example"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357906/what-about-detecting-minimal-reproducible-example) is very similar in intent but with the caveat that this would be specific to the pandas community. Is this something that should be integrated on SO's side of things or should this be a community-sourced bot?