# Will the ask question wizard be on all Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion, ask-question-wizard-2018

I was on wordpress.stackexchange.com and went to ask a question and noticed that the wizard was not present. Do features roll out on Stack Overflow and if the features work they go to all websites or are features independent between the sites?

Comment: Imagine you're active on [Vegetarianism and Veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/). How would you react to "Is your question about code?" as a radio button as the first thing the Wizard presents you with. Or is it "a homework problem"

Comment: There are other coding websites on stackexchange would they not benefit from the wizard @RobertLongson further more Im sure that it could be handed down to the community to customize the wizard to fit the needs of the site

Comment: Those other sites have neither the scale of Stack Overflow, nor its severe quality problems. See background [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page#comment364479_326868).

Comment: It would be nice to have it in international SO sites.

Answer (score 19):

To my understanding, the New Question wizard is specific to Stack Overflow.  Other sites in the network don't get nearly the same traffic to them as SO (think [orders of magnitude less](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)), nor do they have as much of a problem with question quality to necessitate the wizard.

This might change in the future, but for now the feature is very, very Stack Overflow specific.

Comment: Not to mention it would have to be setup for each site individually since the requirements for a good question tend to vary a lot from site to site.

Comment: @JoeW On top of the fact that each site is a totally different topic/group of sub-topics, requiring individually tailored steps/options.